# Getting to know you: who are you and why do spend time on unix.se?

Tags: discussion, fun

I thought it would be a nice idea if we could have a question thread where everyone posts an answer where they introduce themselves, talk about themselves a little bit, and tell the community their motivation for participating on [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site.

Some SE sites don't have much of a community (in the sense of people talking directly to each other), but unix.sx does have something of one, if only composed of people who hang out in chat, and community should be encouraged - there is never enough of it.

So, unless you are royalty going incognito, step up and tell us all about yourself, and why you hang out here. :-)

Comment: +1 Great topic! It's really sad that this is only the second question ever asked here to be tagged `/fun` :)

Comment: Isn't it what the _about me_ of your profile is for?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Well, maybe, but... your "about me" is blank. :-)

Comment: What should the incognito royalty do? Is there a thread for us?

Comment: @mikeserv - can't you use your about your 'about me', even if it is not blank...

Comment: @Wilf - I might have, but after looking at yours, I refuse to play. You've already won.

Comment: This is the post I want to die one day with..

Answer (score 51):

#### Who am I (currently)

I'm a computer engineer who's worked professionally first in electronic design (primarily as a design automation engineer for ~10+ years), followed by a stint in [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) for 5+ years. I'm currently a Software Engineer working on web technologies, still wearing many hats as DevOps & software development.

#### My past - phase 1

I grew up with a [Tandy TRS-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80) ([color computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80_Color_Computer)), which initially came with 16K RAM, which we had upgraded to 64K (if my memory serves me correctly). Here's a picture.

[image: ss of coco]

```
Release date:       1980
Introductory price: 399 USD
Operating system:   Color BASIC 1.0 / 2.0 / OS-9
CPU:                Motorola 6809E @ 0.895 MHz / 1.79 MHz
Memory:             4 kB / 16 kB / 32 kB / 64 kB / 128 kB / 512 kB
Graphics:           MC6847 Video Display Generator (VDG)
```

This computer carried me for a long time. I used it to play games, write BASIC programs and even got into telecommunications with it on [BBSes (Bulletin Board Systems)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletin_board_system).

***the main screen***

[image: the screen]

It had a cassette tape for storing programs, (`CLOAD` and `CSAVE`) were the commands. In 7th grade I saved enough of my own money to get a modem (300 BAUD), you had to dial phone numbers by hand and then press a red button to connect.

***cassette & modem***

[image: ss of cassette]          [image: 300 bps modem]

#### My past - phase 2

In the summer between 4th and 5th grade (9-10 years old) I got the chance to do 1 week's worth of computer programming on an Apple IIe. After that week I was hooked. I begged my mom to sign me up for another more in depth second week where we wrote little guessing game programs and a State Captiols game.

At the start of 5th grade I was the only kid that knew anything about our Apple IIe that we had in class, so I got tasked with showing everyone else how to use it, loading games etc. Our teacher would let me stay after to use it, and I did regularly. Our school also got a teletype machine, which was my first exposure to telecommunications, which ultimately drove me to wanting to get my own modem and exploring that world more.

***Teletype machine (similar to this one)***

[image: telewriter]

#### My past - phase 3

When I was in the 10th grade (14-15 yrs.) I got an actual PC ([Intel 8088](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8088) - I think). It had a cool [turbo button](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_button) so it could run at ~5MHz. I don't know what other specs this system had, it ran some version of MS-DOS (3.3?), since I didn't really know much about such things at that time. I was the only tech type in my family, no one else was into such things, and so I really only had myself to extend my knowledge.

Amazingly the libraries in my city would allow you to check out software. So you could "check out" games, [Print Shop Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Print_Shop), in addition to productivity applications so I did!

At some point I purchased a 2400 Baud modem and started using that with this system as well, again getting into the whole BBS thing that was popular at the time. I'd use [Kermit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_%28protocol%29), [XMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM), [YMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YMODEM), & [ZMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM), as well as my beloved [Telix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telix) to connect and upload and download shareware & chat.

[image: telix]

[image: ss of BBS]

This ultimately was the computer that I took to college. I was one of the few people that had a computer in their dorm room when I went. I had a 24 bit dot matrix printer for it too. I think it was me an 1 other computer guy, so I'd use it to explore [my college's VAX/VMS (Release 4 or 5)](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/%7Ecs1604/notes/chap6/bitnetnodes.html). It was also at this time I got exposed to online gaming ([VAXMUD](http://mud.wikia.com/wiki/VAXMUD)).

Gaming was fun but never really held my attention. I was much more enthralled with the computer system itself, so I purchased a VAX/VMS book and began learning the command line interface, as well as, interacting with other users within the system using the built-in chat functions. Yes believe it or not instance messaging was available back then.

#### My past - phase 4

After my first year I transferred to another university where I was exposed to assembly level programming as well as the [Zilog Z80 micro processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zilog_Z80). Writing in assembly was probably my favorite activity. We'd create banking applications and write various programs and I absolutely loved writing at that level.

**NOTE:** We used [`MASM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) and [`debug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_%28command%29) [(manual)](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/debug.htm) which used to be included with MS-DOS.

#### My past - phase 5

I eventually moved up to a Intel [486DX2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_80486) system that I saved up for and got MS-DOS 5 and then 6.22 and [Windows For Workgroups (3.11)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x#Windows_for_Workgroups_3.11). I then got 2 systems, when I added a 486DX4 that I built myself, for the first time!

At this point I started getting into networking and got my first Ethernet card (10MB 3COM 509). The reason I remember this is because back in the day these cards were [ISA based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture).

[image: 3COM 509]

You really had to want to make peripherals and addon cards work back then. So you had to play a lot of games with changing the memory addresses and interrupts (IRQs) assigned to your various devices, as well as your COM1, COM2, serial ports, and LPT1 ports. So consequently you got to know your systems *very well*!

I eventually added a CDROM (1x) (you now how they're all 52x now - this was the first, a whopping 150 KiB/s!). This was also the time that I got the game [Myst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myst). Hands down the best game I've ever played!

[image: ss of myst]

#### My past - phase 6

As a consequence of building my own computers I used to frequent a [monthly computer fair (Peter Trapp)](http://www.ferretronix.com/tech/hobby.html) in our area to get parts and see what was new and interesting.

[image: ss of show announcement]

Well at one of these events there was a booth where they were either giving away or selling (can't remember) CD sets with something called Linux on them. This booth was a Red Hat booth, and I'd gotten a very early edition of [RHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux).

I then graduated and started my professional career. One of the first things I purchased was a copy of RHL 4.1 (*Vanderbilt, kernel ver. 2.0.27*). Once I got my hands on this I was always working to get rid of Windows in my personal computing environments.

First I started with servers. I used to have a dial on demand setup that would automatically dial via a 28KBps modem, then a 56KBps modem using a Linux box running [`diald`](http://diald.sourceforge.net/FAQ/diald-faq.html), any time someone would attempt to surface the internet. I then graduated to broadband and RHL 9. These early versions are when I completely dumped Windows and was using Linux exclusively day to day.

When Red Hat discontinued RHL, I was almost ready to jump to Debian, but then Fedora came out and then CentOS and I stayed. I toyed a bit with Gentoo, Mandrake, Ubuntu, and Debian, but I always came back to my RPM based distros. Many here will joke that I'm the Red Hat guy here, I wear that notoriety with honor!

Recently (2014) I finally jumped from Fedora 14 to 19, and I still haven't been disappointed. Things change, but all in all the bar has always been moving up.

#### Areas of expertise

I have a very diverse range of areas, in what I would consider having a **deep** knowledge. These are in no particular order.

*Server technologies*

- Samba (2,3, & 4)
- NIS
- NFS (3 & 4)
- DNS (Bind 9)
- Apache/Nginx
- Oracle (9i, 10g, 11g)
- MySQL/MariaDB (all versions)
- PosgreSQL
- JBOSS/Jetty/Tomcat
- [GridEngine/Open Grid Scheduler](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/)
- SLURM <sup>[link1](http://slurm.net/community/) & [link2](http://slurm.schedmd.com/)</sup>
- [Flex Licensing](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/)
- Elasticsearch & *beats

*Security/Auth*

- Kerberos
- SAML/Shibboleth

*Hadoop*

- Zoo Keeper
- HDFS
- HBase
- Hive
- MapReduce
- Yarn

*Virtualization*

- KVM
- VirtualBox
- VMWare
- OpenVZ
- libvirtd
- virt-manager
- Vagrant
- Docker
- Openstack
- AWS
- RHEV/RHV
- Kubernetes/Openshift

*Protocols*

- HTTP/HTTPS
- SSL

*Languages*

- Perl
- Bash
- sed, awk, grep
- Java/JDK
- Javascript
- Ruby
- Python
- Go

*Markups*

- Textile
- Markdown
- XWiki
- HTML
- XML/XSL (including stylesheets)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/)

*Diagnostics*

- Hardware issues
- Performance issues
- Networking issues
- Usability issues

*Monitoring*

- Nagios
- Wireshark
- A whole slew of misc. tools such as: (ntop, htop, nethogs, etc.)

*Desktops*

- GNOME

*OSes*

- Linux (Red Hat, Ubuntu, Debian - all versions)
- Solaris (6,7,8,9, & 10)
- Windows (Vista, Win7, 2008, 2008R2, Win10)

#### Why I'm here?

If you haven't gotten this from reading my history, acquiring the knowledge of how various technologies work, was at times arduous. This has always bugged me because it consumed enormous amounts of my time in acquiring this knowledge, that once I had, was obvious.

So I liken myself to a lighthouse operator now, trying to help others avoid the "cliffs", by hopefully guiding them through the "safe passage" while making mention of key landmarks on either side as they pass through. All I ask in return is that people in turn ["pay it forward"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)!.

#### Compliments

This may seem like a dumb category but one day in the chat room @terdon paid me the highest compliment I think one could ever receive:

*"The way I see it, Stephane is some kind of mythical, magical creature, Gilles is a wizard and slm is a human paladin."*

#### References

- [TRS-80 Computers: TRS-80 Model I Permalink: http://www.trs-80.com/wordpress/trs-80-computer-line/model-i/ Page Attributes: NONE](http://www.trs-80.com/trs80-models-model1.htm)
- [old-computers.com](http://www.old-computers.com/news/default.asp)
- [Free Software for DOS Communication & Internet – 1](http://www.bttr-software.de/freesoft/comm1.htm#term)

Comment: Hi slm. Impressive historical overview. I guessed it was you writing about a quarter of the way through this. :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha - I'll take that as a compliment 8-). It was fun actually trying to find out about all these old things I used to use. I was amazed at how much of it is still thriving. One interesting thing I noticed was it's hard to find photos of any of the older releases of Linux. I couldn't find any RHL 4 for example or older. I'm assuming the advent of digital photography would be the reason, but there is a bit of a line that cuts things off around years 1999-2000.

Comment: You must have spent a lot of time putting this together. I sort of recognized your writing style, but there aren't many people here who would write something as detailed as this, and some of those would either not answer the question or aren't that interested in hardware. Suggestion: add approximate dates to some of the events your chronicle. After all, what is history without dates? :-)

Comment: @FaheemMitha - I think I spent ~3hrs in researching and writing this up.

Comment: You know you're getting old if you have to spend time researching your _own_ history ;)

Comment: @terdon - yeah but it was fun trying to recall memories that I hadn't had to in 20 years too. I still cannot remember the name of the computer company that made that 8088 system. It had some MS-DOS desktop app (I think called Omiworks) but couldn't find it. I really wanted a screenshot of that stuff.

Comment: Glad to meet you here on the forum.  Very instructive, as always.

Comment: @slm, If someone reads this "About me" section of yours, they can realize how much passionate you are about Linux :) It is really inspiring to read your "About me" section :)

Comment: Kudos for the work, many do not value the time it takes to write a well structured post.

Comment: No doubt at all, you are the man. I am very glad that I know one person who knows Linux history more than any one I knew around.And Thank you for sharing

Comment: I would upvote this for the "compliments" section alone.  :D

Comment: I would like to meet in personal Stephane, Slm, Terdon and Gilles, the apparent hidden champions.

Answer (score 33):

I'm a [bioinformatician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics)/computational biologist or whatever, with a background in biology and no formal computer/programming training. Like the good little geek I am, I started using Linux some time around 1998 with the now defunct Mandrake. I then moved to SuSE (pre-novell days), briefly into openSuSE and then Ubuntu when that came out. Couple of years later I switched to Linux Mint and from there to Linux Mint Debian edition which is essentially Debian testing with some bells and whistles. I switched to Arch in the summer of 2016 and will probably be sticking with it for a while.

My *nix expertise, if I can grace it with such a lofty title, is mostly on manipulating text and regular expressions since that represents a large chunk of my daily work. I've learnt more about shell scripting in the year or so that I've been hanging out here than I did in the previous 10. My favorite scripting language, and I'm sure this will come as a surprise to the regulars, is Perl. I spend a lot of time on U&L because I enjoy solving short, concise problems: it's fun!

On a more personal note, I am the son of a Greek mother and American father, and grew up in Greece as a bilingual child. I then went off to study in the UK, did my PhD in Barcelona and my post doctoral work in France. As a result, I sometimes get my languages mixed up which is a source of some embarrassment since I tend to be a grammar pedant.  When I'm not answering questions here or trying to solve life's mysteries, I play my beautiful [Gretsch](https://www.gretschguitars.com/gear).

Comment: hey why terdon get more upvote than the other ?

Comment: @Kiwy 'cause I'm cooler. Obviously.

Comment: @terddon Obviously indeed

Comment: @Kiwy You need to stop asking questions when you know the answer...

Comment: @FaheemMitha this one was a bit too obvious and I couldn't find the answer :D

Comment: @terdon What field in bioinformatics? :)

Comment: @Dovah my PhD was on gene prediction (specifically, selenoprotein gene prediction) and I'm now working on PPI networks. You?

Comment: @terdon I'm still a bachelor student, I'm currently having a summer training in protein mapping.

Comment: "*It had a cool turbo button*", which was a great marketing presentation.  In reality it was a "*run really slowly so that ancient programs will still work on this faster CPU*" button.  Many programs used "*loop 1000 times on a no-op instruction*" to create a delay based on the number of CPU clock cycles.  When run on a newer CPU with a clock speed 100 times faster, a 10 second delay would finish in 100 ms, making games finish rather quickly.

Answer (score 25):

#### Who am I?

I'm a 15-year-old in 10th grade (as of this writing) so I don't have a fascinating job to tell you all about. I've always been super interested in technology and programming. My first language was Visual BASIC, but thankfully, I was never quite motivated enough to make a large program in it (especially since I got confused by all the Windows toolkit stuff), so I never really picked up bad habits from it. I spend a lot of my free time reading things on the internet (think GNOME Wiki, FreeDesktop specs, interesting bugs that are linked to in Mozilla lists, Wikipedia, etc). Things in my RSS reader: EFF Deeplinks, Planet GNOME, blog.SE, Defective by Design, the FSF blog and the GitHub blog. I also love Ultimate Frisbee, although recently I have stopped doing that and have been using basically all my spare time for the [FIRST Tech Challenge](http://www.usfirst.org/roboticsprograms/ftc/game).

I <3 the open internet. I follow Fight For the Future, EFF, and related organizations, and despise all things censorship/anti-net neutrality. I'm anti-DRM because I find it unethical that I have to hand control of my own computer to someone else in order to watch a movie. Honestly, everything I've just said you could find in my bio. Go look at that if you wish I wrote more in this section.

I swear on Meteor.js, Arch GNU/Linux, Emacs, git, and zsh. I use a Happy Hacking Keyboard Professional 2 (white, no key labels), which has prompted the question "why are you using a keyboard from the 90s?" from many of my friends.

#### What was my first *nix?

tl;dr: I used Ubuntu for a while, then Darwin, then I used Ubuntu for a couple months before switching to Arch.

(Some background: around the time that my parents decided it was time for me to have a personal computer, so that theirs wouldn't be screwed up when I made mistakes, I really wanted a Mac, but they got me a Vista computer instead.)

About  years ago, I was in carpool and noticed that the guy who was sitting in front of me was using something not familiar to me, so I asked him what it was, and he replied that it was a different operating system called Ubuntu. I thought that was really interesting, so eventually I ended up installing Ubuntu Gutsy on my laptop. While on Ubuntu, I picked up some rudimentary command-line skills, but couldn't do a ton (I have a clear memory of being on vt1, killing a process, but having to switch back to Xorg to look up a PID in Activity Monitor [since I didn't know about `ps`]). I stayed with Ubuntu all the way up until Ubuntu Maverick, as that was the point at which I received an iMac as a gift. From then on, I used OS X, although I always missed GNU/Linux a bit.

While on OS X I solidified a bunch of my command-line skills. However, I never really did anything (comparatively) advanced like I/O redirection or pipes. Then, about a year ago, Steam was ported to GNU/Linux, removing the last barrier to me going back. I used Ubuntu for about 3 months, until I had gotten a sufficient feel for the community to become angry at Canonical (and GNOME). At that point, I went DE-hopping for a while before I finally ditched for Arch (and awesomewm, although about a month ago I made my peace with GNOME and am back on the GNOME Shell train).

I sysadmin a home server as a hobby. It's named steevie, and has been down for about 4 months due to a disk failure (I think).

As a side note, I've also recently become very interested in [Plan 9 from Bell Labs](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9). I have an server installed, but the Ethernet card(!) isn't recognized.

#### Where do I want to take my UNIX skills next?

I believe I'm the only one here who will actually have an answer to this, so here goes. When I grow up, I want to hack on either GNOME, Mozilla, or GNU. Or, I want to sysadmin for one of those guys. More generally, I aspire to [become a hacker in the classical sense](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html).

In the nearer future, I want to get better at text processing (e.g. learn regexps, `sed`, `awk`, etc.), and just become more familiar with the standard, classic UNIX tools (e.g. `find`). I also want to become more familiar with the shell, as I still can't do a lot of I/O redirections besides stdout, and I certainly don't have the skills to customize my shell properly. It is also a goal of mine to gain mad Emacs-fu.

#### Why do I spend time on unix.SE?

I love learning about UNIX history, and a lot of the people here have great experiences from Back In The Day. Additionally, I am undoubtedly still learning, and I soak up a huge amount of knowledge here.

Like I said, I spend a lot of time reading about GNU/Linux stuff on the internet. So I really like the questions that are phrased as "how does * work on the inside"; they're fun to answer and fun to think about.

Also, to be perfectly honest, I am completely hooked on the gamification of Stack Exchange. Getting reputation and badges is awesome.

Finally, Unix & Linux has an amazing community. I had used Stack Overflow before I found this site, and still do, but the difference is that I can't stand the SO community anymore. Mostly because it's so high-traffic. I like the more relaxed pace here, and I really love that you can actually *know* all the regulars.

Comment: this is probably way more than you asked for. but whatever.

Answer (score 24):

#### [Smash it up!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyjmCg_VMU0#t=30)

I like *destruction.* Not in the smash-it-up kinda way, though that can have its finer points, but more as the reverse of *construction.* I like things *broken* into *pieces* - not just *broken* - because I like to know what goes on inside a thing that makes it tick in the first place. If I'm lucky - and I rarely am - I do get it back together in much the same shape as I found it. But regardless of how successful I am at *reconstructing*, the chances are always pretty good I'll learn something worthwhile during the *destruction.*

That, I think, is why I like Unix - particularly Linux. I like to tear it to pieces and hopefully find out in the aftermath what those pieces did. It teaches me a lot about how computers work. It teaches more, better, and faster than any other system I've ever worked with. I really like to learn.

#### [Early days...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57RIlznOpDM#t=31)

My dad still tells the story of my parents' first microwave. I was barely 3 years old. My younger sister was nearly 2. My mother and father brought the machine home and propped it up on the kitchen table. Neither had ever had a microwave oven before. They didn't know really how one would work. They sat there, reading the instruction manual to each other, and generally poking at it. Eventually they got the hang of it and they put it up - but I sat quietly nearby listening and watching the entire time they were educating themselves.

The next morning my father awoke to the smell of smoke. He went into the kitchen and found that I had decided to cook my sister's breakfast for her - froot loops. Spoon, milk, and all. The reflection from the spoon was of course devastating to the microwave after several minutes cooking the cereal. My dad says today that I might not have lived to see my fourth year if Sear's hadn't taken that microwave back. He'll go on to tell you what a near thing it was for me as well when he found my peanut butter and jelly sandwich in the vcr.

#### [My first computer...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RthZgszykLs#t=57)

I've always liked tech. I like buttons. I like *rules.* My first experience with computers was around the age of 9 or so, I think. My father invested more than $3,000 *(borrowed)* dollars into a 486DX33 with a Diamond Viper VESA video card. It had 8 megabytes of RAM, a 128 megabyte hard drive, and an internal USR 9600 bps dial-up modem. The Intel DX chips came with a built-in math co-processor - this was high-tech stuff.

The video card, math-coprocessor, and modem were all very important to my father because he wanted to learn to trade commodity *futures* - like stock-trading but with soybeans or pork-bellies. He had all the books, and now he could draw up his own charts. Computer-use was not a foreign concept to Dad - he was and is an architect. He had the chart stuff pretty much down pat.

He wasn't very familiar with the command-line though. I think it was DOS 4 we had then, and Windows 3.0. One day he brought home a floppy-disk that was given to him by a colleague for my sake - it was Wolfenstein 3D. That did it. His colleague, I afterward learned, ran a 2-line BBS out of his home, and I was soon a daily-dialing member.

I played Wolfenstein - and it was *awesome.* Plenty of destruction was had. I also had to configure the high-mem and EGA/VGA graphics settings upon boot - at that time, if you wanted to use anything greater than the first 256KB of your memory, you had to deal with `hi-mem.sys` and `config.sys` and `autoexec.bat`. I learned these things - at age 9 - and it wasn't long before my father was asking me how a thing should be done on the computer.

#### [The devil's party-line...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-XuMvxi-vc#t=11)

And the BBSs - I dug up the phone numbers to as many as I could find. I played *Trade Wars 2002* and *Legend of the Red Dragon* - those two were my favorites, but there were others. Also, I eventually learned of and did my best to subscribe to members' only *pirate* BBSs. My goal was selfish - I wanted to download free video games. But it was at that time that I first got a glimpse of the hacker society, and I first learned that some people thought software should be *free.*

I used to steal AOL. I would use the free AOL disks you could get pretty much anywhere and use the 100 or so minutes they'd give you for free completely up before creating a new account and ... you know, rinse, repeat. The thing is - I was not yet a teenager, and the AOL sign-up process required a credit card to complete. I had no such thing. But what I did have was some crappy script - which I downloaded from AOL - that would randomly generate me a usable credit card number once in every ten or so tries. So I used that.

Don't get me wrong - I don't condone stealing, not in the way I used to - but there were some involved with those BBSs that did what they did as a matter of *principle.* Whether or not their principles were a little skewed I cannot say - my impression of them remains to this day only what I could take away at nine and ten years old. But it has lasted.

#### [*Pirates!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9drameYoMek#t=61)

Another thing I downloaded from AOL was a little program called *DisEase*. The computers at school were Macs. Mr. Wolfe, my literature teacher, would occasionally reward an especially good book report with a short while playing *Sid Meyers' Pirates!*. I thought that game was *great* - but I couldn't be bothered to write a book report. Hence, *DisEase.*

You see, their idea of security was a login manager called *At Ease.* If I plugged in my *DisEased* floppy and rebooted the machine, *DisEase* would spit out their password - which I guess they all shared. So every spare moment in my eighth-grade year I was playing *Sid Meyers' Pirates!* - book reports be *damned*! Though, as I later found out, I could have been editing my report card.

Well, I was just a kid, too, you know. I told other kids. They told on me. I was hauled out of the principal's office one day late that school year in handcuffs. The school district settled with my father - and - maybe because he felt a little responsible, though he shouldn't have - Mr. Wolfe got me my first job at his brother-in-law's garden nursery. And I spent the whole summer working to pay for the IT crew they brought in to me-proof their computer systems. They rejected outright my own counterbid for the work. I spent my 13th birthday that August watering azaleas and day-dreaming of *DOOM*.

#### [Scholastically...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjCDeXXvTTc#t=20)

My teenage years tended to separate me from my geekdom, I think. I never lost track of it, but it was cooler to wire car-audio, or to hit the bong. I did both things. I got my GED at sixteen after the latter thing saw me out of school at fifteen.

I tried college at sixteen and seventeen, but for the same reasons I didn't want to go to high-school, I didn't much want to go to college either. Any class in which I was enrolled and for which the prof kept attendance I inevitably failed. The others, though, I aced. And that's how I squandered my first scholarship, which was awarded me for an outstanding score on the GED in the first place.

It was several years later - while enlisted in the US Army - when I finally tried again at the school thing and met with some success. Today I have an associate's degree in nothing in particular and several it certs - but nothing outstanding.

#### [Professionally...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sdILQwlP_pk#t=60)

I worked, pretty much, from age 13 on with few breaks. Restaurants. Gas stations. Garages. No tech. But I would always wind up helping the bosses understand their computers at some point.

Eventually I started selling cellular phones. I did very well. I was always - for the entire year and a half I held the job - the monthly number one cellular salesman in my *Ultimate Electronics* region. That experience brought me the opportunity to work for my uncle at 321Studios selling wholesale his company's flagship product *DVD X Copy.*

I wasn't very good at the wholesale thing - there were four of us in wholesale sales, and I was barely 20 years old when I started the job, while the rest were all seasoned professionals. I was the *nephew* so they would try to help me in the hopes that my uncle would notice - also, I wasn't exactly unlikable. I was fun, if mostly wrong-headed.

#### [Quid pro quo...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sg4BSpuR-Rw#t=46)

In searching for affiliate deals I became an associate of Jim McMahon of [MajorGeeks.com](http://www.majorgeeks.com). We advertised on his site, offered the shareware version of our product for download there, and he collected commission on any conversions tracked to his affiliate link. He's a very nice guy, by the way - and if you ever get him on the phone he'll likely tell you a longer and much more interesting story than this one.

His was not the only site I landed. Though it was Jim who introduced me to another man, whose name I now forget, who brought up a very interesting point.

He said, "So when I download your software from your website I'm asked to opt-in or out of the receipt of emails from your company promoting your product. But I never receive any emails. I think I could write those emails for you," he said, "if you'll allow me to promote other software alongside your own."

This was curious to me, and I brought it to my boss, who was also intrigued. But he said:

"We don't need that guy! We have an entire Creative Department! We can write our own newsletter!"

#### [Damned if you do...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRc_yreVl78#t=10)

Now my cousin was head of the *entire Creative Department* and my uncle liked to keep his son busy. There was little chance of my sneaking through my own project. So I quit going to work for a couple weeks. I holed up at home in my underwear reading every article I could digest at *webmonkey.com.* I did manage to get my cousin's employee - Pete - to do a *Photoshopped* mockup of what he thought a *lorem-ipsum 321Studios* newsletter might look like. I took it and dissected it, wrote the material, and wrote the CSS and HTML I was then learning to make it work.

I showed up to work a couple weeks later. I had been *missed*. My uncle told me the newsletter would go out to our some 500,000 opt-in subscribers the coming Friday afternoon, and I had better hope it worked out because, in the event it didn't, I would need another job.

Well, luckily for me, it was a smashing success! Our web-sales were some 2.5 times their weekend norms. And, of course, those numbers did not maintain - we soon saturated our target audience with weekly editions. I received my own commission for every box sold through my own affiliate link. And, more importantly, I got to keep my job, and now I was the *newsletter editor.* This was influential to me, because our business was not that of your average software company.

#### [David v. Goliath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qoGqVq9EXw#t=38)

You see, our software *DVD X Copy* was a point-and-click Windows-friendly *decss* complete product. You could take an encrypted Hollywood disc, pop it in your DVD-reader, feed your DVD-writer a blank disc, click the big, green "COPY!" button and 20 minutes or so later you had a decrypted copy of that movie. Hollywood was not a fan of *DVD X Copy.*

We were big too - we had our own shelf in Wal-Mart nationwide. International distribution deals, even. Uncle Robert used to fly a helicopter to work. 321Studios did very well for awhile - but it couldn't last.

My uncle was very aware of the possible legal ramifications involved with marketing a post-DMCA software product that subverted commercial encryption techniques, regardless of the encryption's efficacy. My uncle was a *ballsy* man - he preemptively sued Hollywood. Much of 321Studios' profits were invested in the legal ordeal. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_X_Copy):

> Anticipating a lawsuit by the major Hollywood motion picture studios,
> in April 2002, 321 Studios filed a pre-emptive complaint against eight
> Hollywood studios contending that the Digital Millennium Copyright Act
> (DMCA), a law that prohibits the circumvention of copy protection
> technology, violates consumer rights as provided in the Fair Use
> doctrine of the Copyright Act of 1976. The Fair Use doctrine provides
> individuals with limited rights to copy certain forms of copyrighted
> material. The complaint named MGM Studios, Tristar Pictures, Columbia
> Pictures, Sony Pictures Entertainment, Time Warner Entertainment,
> Disney Enterprises, Universal City Studios, The Saul Zaentz Company
> and Pixar Corporation as defendants.

After that first edition newsletter, Uncle Robert made it clear to me that, though I would be responsible for ensuring it continued to be an earner, the weekly newsletter's primary focus must be raising awareness for *Fair Use*. And so, at age 20 and 21 I had the privilege of interacting with and publishing the EFF's Lawrence Lessig among others; I regularly featured news articles surrounding all types of *Fair Use* issues of the day; I often shadow-wrote Robert's own message to our customers - though he always tailored the message in some way; I sponsored *Write Your Congressman* campaigns - and interacted personally with a few of them, not to mention publishing their responses when they could be had. It was a very *political* thing - and it all surrounded the notion of *freedom of information*. Again, this was *influential* to me.

#### [This, too, shall pass...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGM8PT1eAvY#t=12)

As I've said, though, it couldn't last. What kept 321Studios afloat throughout its costly legal ordeal was its profits from the sale of our product. As soon as the judge ruled for an injunction against our sale of it, 321Studios effectively folded. Though the legal battle was never officially lost, it might as well have been because once we sold off the last of our flagship *DVD X Copy* product one week following the judge's injunction, there was no hope of maintaining the fight because, from that point on, there was no way to pay for it. And that marked the end of my *political* career.

Still, I was a wholesale sales agent. And the injunction named only *321Studios.* I did have a few regular distribution deals with resellers, which is not to mention a few more very short-term deals I negotiated in that last week we were still legally allowed to sell the software. The way it worked out was we did better business in that last week, than probably we had done in the entire previous fiscal quarter. My commission check for that last week was close to $40,000 - before taxes, of course.

#### [Be All That You Can Be...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nk1lNqi3AXE)

So there I was - jobless, barely of drinking age, living on my own in a rented house only a short walk's distance to at least three different bars. I did a lot of walking. Six months later, when most of the money was spent, I knew I had to find another job. I didn't much like the idea of looking, though, and while half-heartedly trying I passed an Army recruiter's office. "I bet," I thought, "they'll give me a job!"

I spent the next six years maintaining electronics and weapons systems on the OH-58D Kiowa Warrior observational attack helicopter for my US Army. I saw the tops of mountains and the business end of a grenade launcher. I lived in Hawaii and Alaska. I flew *everywhere.* I got a degree on the Army's dime. I got married and divorced.

While taking an introductory Python course I also took a college algebra course. My math class turned out to be repetitive applications of a single formula per lesson. My Python class wound up doing my math class's homework. And it did so in Ubuntu Linux. My first installation of which was - I believe - 6.04. I kept up with Ubuntu until around 8.04 - I think. And then I started experimenting with Debian proper - but not for long. Soon I was tired of the whole Debian backports game, so I played with Crux, then settled on, at last Arch Linux. This was several years ago. It's my goto still today.

I like Arch because I like to tear it apart, and it comes apart very willingly. Not many others do, you know.

I'll edit this some more later, I guess. It's quite enough for now, I think.

Comment: Wonderful write up! I love the details and the way your life's story winds around the right for fair use. Terrific read!

Comment: Engaging read sir. I can pretty much identify with you in some aspects, through due to some strokes of lady luck, my life seems to have been a bit easier.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro - thats what the upvote button is for.

Answer (score 18):

My name is Kusalananda. I'm one of [your moderators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators).

[image: profile for Kusalananda at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, Q&A for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems]

I work as a government-funded software developer, systems developer, or DevOps engineer in Sweden.  I am accustomed to working in very international teams, and my current job involves supporting the larger academic community of bioinformaticians at Swedish research institutions (universities). In the Unix & Linux forum, I seem to be mainly interested in **shell script programming** and **Unix tools**, but I also enjoy programming in C and Perl, and Python when I'm forced to it. I quite like meddling in SQL too.

My father gave me a Commodore 64 when I was 13, and later an Amiga 500.  I used them mainly for playing games, but also for learning Basic.

The best computer I've ever owned was a Macintosh SE/30 which served me well during the first few years of university in the early 90s. For its time, it was a real power brick in a neat and compact design. I'm terribly sad that I sold it.

During the early 1990's I rapidly progressed though a number of Apple machines while at the same time doing most of my actual programming for classes (mostly in C++ and Fortran 90 at the time) on SUN SPARCstations and SUN Ultra workstations running this Unix thing (earlier versions of **Solaris**, or possibly SunOS, I'm not entirely sure). I learned to use the system by solving tasks related to my programming assignments, and by testing random commands to see what they did. I never took a "Unix class". I knew how to write a Makefile before I knew very much about shell programming.

My department was a *Scientific Computing* department, not a Computer Science department, and I started out on a Ph.D. in numerical analysis. Numerical analysis involves solving systems of equations using iterative methods. I soon found that I was more interested in (and better at) the actual implementation of the methods than working out the linear algebra.

For my Ph.D. project I was implementing a parallel preconditioner for the Euler and Navier-Stokes' equations in Fortran 77, using PVM to do the message passing between the four supercomputers we had at the department. PVM (Parallel Virtual machine), for those that may not know, was (is?) a bit like the development test-bed for MPI, the Message Passing Interface.

Being a Ph.D. student in Sweden is a bit different than what's it like in e.g. Britain. You're employed, you have a salary, you have an office, you teach. I taught Object Oriented Analysis and Design with C++ and a bit of parallel programming using PVM and MPI with Fortran 90 and C. I also ran an after-hours help desk in the department's computer lab, helping students with everything from printer problems to sorting out their programming logic.

I enjoyed helping. I enjoyed teaching.

Love and boredom made me quit the Ph.D. and we moved to New Zealand, for *her* Ph.D. in biochemistry. By this time (2000), I've had a cursory glance at **Debian GNU/Linux**, but had decided I thought it was too "sprawling" and not "well defined" enough. I ran **NetBSD** on a decommissioned SUN Blade workstation for a while, while working for a Life Science Crown Research Institute outside Dunedin, maintaining a cluster of RedHat servers and doing general programming odd-jobs for the people there needing it.

Since December 2000 and OpenBSD 2.8 I've used **OpenBSD** as my main platform. For about 11 years, I did a lot of Perl and SQL for a large project at the EMBL-EBI and the Wellcome Trust in the UK (these places do research in bioinformatics and biomedicine), but I finally moved back to Sweden in 2014 for the position that I'm currently at.

My current setup is a macOS system on which I run OpenBSD-current in a VirtualBox headless virtual machine instance (10 GiB disk, 1 CPU, and a whooping 1 GiB of RAM seems to be what I need). Then I have a couple of OpenBSD laptops playing file servers, mail servers and other types of servers. All my work happens in or via the OpenBSD system while macOS provides me with a browser and a Slack client, and not much else.

What do I do here?

- I'm an elected moderator, so I do moderating.
- I take a particular interest in shell scripting and Unix tools questions in general.
- I (hopefully) write answers that are clear and easy to understand.
- I learn a lot from people that know more than I do. A *whole* lot.
- I get annoyed with GNU-isms (when taken as universal standard) and with people that don't know that there are other Unices besides Linux.

Why am I here?

- I like helping individuals with getting things done.
- I get a kick out of seeing someone else learn something.
- I enjoy short and self-contained problems.
- I like learning more about things I know only little about.
- I need to keep my brain working.
- I enjoy this community.

Unix systems, in order of preference:

1. OpenBSD
2. NetBSD
3. Linux (Ubuntu, probably)
4. Solaris
5. Anything else that looks *interesting*. I've played around with Minix (but the lack of Dvorak key mappings put me off) and even had a go on the GNU Hurd, and Plan 9 (9front), just to be able to say I was there.

   FreeBSD has been *totally* uninteresting to me, but I can't really say why.  I like "small" systems, which is why I stick to OpenBSD.  I only just recently installed my first FreeBSD virtual machine to have a system to test some of my own software on.  Likewise, I keep an Ubuntu Linux system around, but I never really use it.  At work, we have multi-user servers and clusters (real and virtualized) running Ubuntu.

Things I believe I can say I know something about:

- Shell script programming
- POSIX tools
- C programming
- SQL
- GNU autotools (`autoconf` and `automake`)

My approach to answering questions in this forum (I don't strictly follow this):

1. Answer the question.
2. Solve the problem.  For example, the question may be about syntax, but the problem is about copying files or parsing a file.
3. Explain.

Unix-related achievements benefiting others:

- I helped out with reviving the lost `groff` sources of the [Unix Text Processing](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/utp/) book.
- I maintain the ports of [GNU Stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/), [sshguard](https://www.sshguard.net/), and [Anacron](https://sourceforge.net/projects/anacron/) for OpenBSD. I previously also maintained some more obscure ones.
- I maintain a tiny software project I call [`shell-toolbox`](https://github.com/kusalananda/shell-toolbox) which I use for testing solutions to questions on this site.

Other odd Unix-related facts:

- I run `zsh` as my login shell.
- I prefer `groff` over LaTeX.
- My main editor is `vi` (`nvi`).
- My six most used shell command are, according to my history file,

  1. `doas`
  2. `ls`
  3. `less`
  4. `man`
  5. `cd`
  6. `vi`

[image: Recent screenshot]

---

*Kusalananda* is very much a given name, albeit not my legal name.

Comment: Thanks. [Is doas really OpenBSDs replacement for sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237230/674)

Comment: @Tim Yes, very much so. https://xkcd.com/1343/  The OpenBSD developers were concerned that `sudo` had become too big and too difficult to configure safely.  `doas` is a _much_ simpler tool. It's [configuration manual](http://man.openbsd.org/doas.conf) is tiny.

Comment: Have you written in a bit more detail somewhere how doas is different from sudo, would love to learn more about how it's different.

Answer (score 14):

I've been using Linux-based operating systems since the summer of 1998, which coincided with the purchase of my first computer. I had used computers for a while before that, but they had been VAX, Suns, Windows and Macs. I think that time was my first exposure to a "real" operating system.

I started with Red Hat 5.1 (version inferred based on the date, I don't remember now), moved on to SuSE 6.2 in the summer of 1999, and eventually to Debian in 2001, having being considering that move for a while before that. I've used Debian pretty much exclusively since then, and in general I count myself satisfied. My one attempt to package something for Debian, namely CCL, has so far not borne fruit. It was rejected by the ftpmasters, who have still not replied to my response. :-(

My background is mathematical, but I've got a PhD in Statistics, and have published a few research papers, though mostly not in Statistics. I really need to set up a website. I've done a lot of programming off and on. My knowledge of things Unix is actually fairly rudimentary, but I'm quite familiar with Debian, so I tend to answer questions about that.

I frequent this site because I have found the Stack Exchange sites useful, particularly Stack Overflow. However, I don't really have very good or specialist knowledge about anything. I've worked across a lot of different areas so I'm something of a perpetual beginner. Plus I'm generally too lazy and/or too busy to put much effort into answering questions. For whatever reason, I tend to find it easiest to answer questions here, and the atmosphere is friendly and supportive, so I do so.

The other SE site I frequent regularly is TeX.sx, which is also friendly. I'm a long time user of LaTeX, though again I know relatively little about it. And of course, everyone uses Stack Overflow, though it is too large to have a community, and I have not found it to be the friendliest of places.

Comment: What is your current position, in which topic do you `make money`? Sorry, I know the question only refers to the first part of `your question`.

Answer (score 14):

#### Unix background

I've been working as a unix sysadmin since 1998, when I started as postmaster/spammer killer at one of the three largest ISPs in Sweden. Back then most of our systems were Solaris, with a few FreeBSD thrown in. FreeBSD is still my favourite free Unix.

I stayed at Algonet^WTelenordia^WTelenor^WTelenor Business Solutions^WTelenor for 8 years through multiple reorganisations. During that time the number of emails handled by our system rose by a few orders of magnitude. The qmail servers I started out working with got enhanced by a load-balancer with multiple bells and whistles built in Erlang, which is still the most stable email system I've ever had the pleasure to work with. In addition to handling the email systems, I spent time on pretty much all other customer-facing systems. Since all those systems were of necessity open to the Internet, that meant handling security issues as well.

After that I went to work at one of the major banks in Sweden, where I handled a crucial part of the security systems for their internet banking sites. This was built on HP-UX which I still see as one of the best OSs for security purposes. Their combination of compartments and RBAC made it possible to have a very fine-grained approach to what each single process was able to do and see on the server. Obviously I can't go into details on how exactly it was implemented, but [HP-UX Security Containment basics](https://h20392.www2.hp.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=SecurityExt) describes the technology (until the next time they rebuild their website and destroy all links...)

After eight years of that, I got tired of doing the same thing and got hired by a consultancy firm in 2013. My first gig for them was with a government agency handling their RHEL servers, looking at the next Redhat satellite, automating things and generally just sysadminning. It was a nice change of pace. After that, I worked at the Swedish Police with their PKI department, which was fun and interesting. I spent most on my time on revocation and OCSP systems. Currently I'm focusing on PKI; I'm working with a client setting up an entire PKI system from scratch, which is a lot more fun than working with a system where you're constrained by decisions made many years ago.

#### Before that

By looking at my profile you could have figured out that I was in my mid-20s before I got my first sysadmin job. I wasn't one of those kids who grew up around computers - my family couldn't afford it, and it wasn't on my radar at all. I did enjoy the few computer lessons we got at school, though, and generally ended up being the informal TA in that everyone asked me questions before asking the teacher.

My first ~7 years of working life were spent in a few different jobs - shipping agency, translator... During that time, for the first time I could actually afford computer equipment and discovered more and more. I decided that unix sounded like what I wanted to work with, got a day job doing tech support at a phone company (that's internal tech support for their employees, not for their customers) and went to uni night classes to learn basic programming/system design. After that, I got the job at Algonet and have happily remained a unix sysadmin since.

#### Programming

I'm a sysadmin, Jim, not a programmer. Still, in order to be a decent sysadmin one has to be able to create new tools as needed, so I do a fair bit of that as well.

Like many unix admins of my generation, I started out with shell scripts, perl and some C. (I am really not good at C; I can usually manage minor patches to existing programs but I'm really crap at e.g. memory allocation and other stuff beyond Hello World...)

Perl is my language of choice for most of the things I do as a sysadmin. It's got better data structures than shell scripts, and it's ubiquitous. It's also old enough to have most of its major bugs already ironed out.

I've found that I became a better programmer when I started learning other types of languages. Perl, shell script and C are all procedural languages. Once I started looking at OO languages like Java and, later, Ruby, I got a new way of looking at things. And when I got into Erlang I was completely hooked, and also found that my perl programs got both more elegant and more readable thanks to the habits I learned from using Erlang.

So in the three categories "procedural, OO, functional", my favourite languages are perl, Ruby and Erlang.

#### Why I'm here

I like solving problems. No, scratch that - I **love** solving problems. Figuring out why something doesn't work and fixing it is a huge high for me. I also remember all the help I got, from complete strangers as well as from friends, when I started out, and I want to pay it forward. This is why I answer a lot more than I ask, both here and on http://serverfault.com where I also hang out.

This site fills three needs for me:

- the need to give back what was given to me
- the need to find new puzzles and to solve them
- the need to procrastinate while still finding and learning new things

And the chat room gives me a chance to stay in touch with other people with similar interests. What's not to like?

#### Other stuff

I'm a horse rider; I have a horse of my own. Consequently I have no spare time to worry about. In what little I have, I enjoy crafts (knitting, sewing, weaving...) and playing WoW (Argent Dawn, EU, I'm in the Plainrunners Tribe). I'm married, to a man who used to be a sysadmin and is now a developer/architect. It's nice to be with someone who understands the technical issues I work with; it makes for interesting conversations while driving to work... I live in Sweden, some ways outside of Stockholm where I work.

Answer (score 14):

**About me**

My name's LE Manh Cuong, from Hanoi, Vietnam.

I have not graduated from University yet, and I'm not going to do that. (There are many reasons, but that's another story). In University, I learned about Electronic and Telecommunication. All my knowledge about IT fields came from online learning (Thanks Coursera, edX, OCW) and researching by myself (Thanks Professor Google).

I have worked in IT fields for about 3 years, as a Network Engineer, a System Administrator and a Perl Developer. Now I'm doing a startup with my friend, It's a mobile marketing system. In future, I'm going to become a DevOps Engineer because I love System Administrator as much as Programming.

My first OS was Windows, but I switched to Linux when I got a job as a Linux System Administrator, and I did not know that I have loved it since when.

Everyday, I learn more about Linux, reading papers, documentation, doing some labs, writing some code. Knowing, discovering and explaning how things work, how things can be done like that make me feel great.

**Why U&L**

My goal is sharing and learning more things about Linux (or *nix), and I feel I got it when I first was here. Reading answers and questions from people (like terdon, slm, Gilles, Stéphane Chazelas and others whom I have not remember yet) is awesome. Learning from community is awesome, too.

Helping people solving problem, get feedback from community, make solution better. This process make me (and people) better.

**My skills**

I have worked on many Linux distro (Ubuntu, Centos, Arch, OpenSUSE...), some *nix (Solaris, AIX, OSX). Many skills that I have learned to work with them. Some skills that I am good at:

- Bash (and other *nix shell)
- Vim
- Perl
- AWK
- Apache
- Nagios
- Salt stack
- Haproxy

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's nice to see so many people that are similar minded 8-).

Comment: Thanks for writing. We don't seem to get a lot of people from Asia here, and I had not noticed anyone from Vietnam before. Though I see you do list Hanoi as your location in your profile.

Answer (score 12):

I've been using Linux since 1996 (I think -- early 2.0.x kernels) starting with Red Hat and quickly switching to Slackware.  In the time since then I've used many other distributions and my go-to distro is Debian.  I've also worked with AIX on RS/6000, VMS on VAX, Digital Unix on Alpha and SCO before they became what they are today.

I currently have 4 machines, running Gentoo, Debian, Ubuntu* and OS X.

My motivation for being here is to help where I can.  Over the years (and increasingly so) when I need to Google something, a SE site pops up that tells me exactly what I need.  I've taken a lot from SO/*.SE and felt it was time to give something back.

Currently, I'm a Ph.D. student of meteorology (severe storms and tornadoes).  Before that I flew the Embraer-145 regional jet for a regional airline for a number of years. I have also been employed as a programmer on and off over the years.

*<sub>on armhf and I'll be switching that once I have to time to setup a proper cross compile environment</sub>

Comment: I have a cross compiling environment in Linux however it is so much easier to compile small things in my Lamobo R1 with a SSD disk...

Answer (score 12):

I'm just another geek who got addicted to programming when I was 11. My first languages were JavaScript and then C. Unfortunately on that other OS :(

Somehow I happened to find a career in programming when I was 16. I build windows apps and web apps. While I have a good job writing a giant web app product, it all seems like stamp collecting when I read about how a young Finnish guy wrote an OS that runs half the internet.

I've been meaning to get into the *nix world for ever so long (and eventually into kernel develop or anything close to the hardware). Lack of resources and being on my own made it a hard journey. Finally the time came when I was rejected for a job because I lacked *nix skills I swore I would pick it up, that's when I came here.

A year later today I own OSX, Fedora and Windows (for the day job :( ) I picked up Perl, a little Python and Haskell. I contributed into the Perl Core and Dancer2 (Perl Web Framework). and I'm re-learning C the Unix way now.

The last few months I've tried dabbling with toy OS's. Some Assembly, the Raspberry Pi and the Linux source code. However it has been blatantly hard! :/ Understanding how to interact with hardware, what manuals to read etc have just been daunting.

I don't know what steps to take next, but I know I have a long journey and I'll be programming for a while.

Comment: what other os??

Comment: @mike windows :P

Answer (score 11):

**Who I am**

I'm an electronics and telecomm. engineer by training. I'm currently pursuing a master's degree in the field (specializing in [MEMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microelectromechanical_systems)) in my hometown of Cairo, Egypt. I also work as a teaching assistant for a couple of undergraduate courses at my university.

When I'm not doing techie stuff, I'm an avid reader of literature and poetry. I'm a big time *Lord of the Rings* nerd. Give me a shout out if you are/were a fellow member of [Entmoot](http://entmoot.tolkientrail.com/) :)

**My *nix history**

I'm quite a late comer to the *nix world, I'm afraid. My first brush with it was in the early 2000's (2001~2002) when my father bought a computer magazine that came with a Mandrake LiveCD. I popped it in, booted from it, understood nothing and went happily on my Windows way. It wasn't until 2009 that I had a true introduction to GNU/Linux (as well as a very brief stint on a Solaris machine) via RHEL in an enterprise setting. This was during an internship for an electronics company that required me to learn the use of Red Hat (and Perl) for a scripting job.

After the internship was over, I was still reluctant to move my whole workflow over to GNU/Linux. The experience did draw me closer to the free software world, though, and Perl and LaTeX stuck with me in my Windows environment.

It was in early 2010 that I finally made the full leap because I was required to 
work on some simulation software for college that only worked under GNU/Linux. I switched to a Mandriva 2010 environment based on my TA's recommendation.

When I graduated, I came into contact with a mixed environment of Mandriva 2010 and Mandriva 2011 boxes in the workplace as well as some CentOS (can't remember which version) boxes in the graduate research lab at school.

Since electronics people are not computer/programming-inclined by training or nature<sup>1</sup>, and since my TA who recommended that I use Mandriva had left school to pursue other things, I was the only one knowledgeable enough to manage the research lab's network of (really ancient) CentOS boxes.

Since then, I have been incrementally learning system administration (and scripting skills) and have found it to be quite an enjoyable, albeit stressful, profession. I have recently revamped the lab with a pre-seeded installation of Debian Wheezy managed by Puppet, which has proven quite robust so far.

On my personal computer, I have used Mandriva 2010, Debian Squeeze, Fedora 16 and Debian Wheezy in this order. I am currently waiting for some free time to try out Arch and Slackware so I can delve even deeper.

Oh, and I also tried out LFS v7.1 but haven't had the time to play with it as much as I'd hoped.

My weapon of choice for most tasks (professional or personal) is Perl.

**Why I come here**

I was once faced with an administration problem at work and couldn't find suitable Google search terms for it. Since StackExchange sites were always helpful during my Google searches, I signed up here and [asked my question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55014/why-does-ssh-not-consult-etc-hosts) and received the correct answer all in less than an hour. I have been a frequent visitor here ever since. First I asked questions then, as my experience grew, I became comfortable answering them as well. I second [terdon's sentiment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2673/26909) that I have learned more about GNU/Linux by frequenting this site and interacting with people than I ever did by reading.

---

<sup>1</sup>With a few exceptions, obviously :)

Comment: Nice answer, Joseph. Thanks for writing!

Comment: Thank _you_ for the question. It was really inspired :)

Answer (score 11):

( I was pointed out that the prose could use some re-reading and correction, I will do so when as soon as I have some time (and feel like doing so, fixing someone else's errors is different))

I'm a General Linguist by education and software developer by trade. I use Linux whenever I can, for specific tasks I use Windows or an Arduino (I prefer the Arduino: less restrictions).

I like U&L as I found answers to many of my questions there or better solutions than I have come up with myself over the years. It also points out interesting (that is of course subjective) subjects that I never thought I wanted to know about in the first place. I don't read the new questions systematically, but being active on the review queues show me a fair share of them.

**Some history**

I used to play with my brother's slide-ruler (he was a few years older
and has a more technical education), and I was fascinated by the electronic
calculator I did see at the
[evoluon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evoluon). Mine graduation year was the last
year that was not allowed to use a calculator for the final exams
(the ones before going to university), and I am glad of that, because I think that
forced me to learn to be able to do calculations on paper or in my head
quickly.

In the final year in school I almost did some programming. But the
teacher explained that that would have involved sending pencil marked
punch-cards to a university, equipped with a computer to process the programs,
and that would have been a week or two round-trip time (this was 1978).

Not until I started studying Mathematics (there was no separate computer
science at that time) at Leiden University at seventeen, did I have my
first real experience with programming, on  a IBM 370 compatible Amdahl system. We, the
first year students, had limited resources allocated for our "jobs". This was determined by the job-control
punch-cards that you put in front of your actual program cards (in ALGOL 60). 
I soon found out how to increase the run-time limitations we had to several seconds and to more than 4 pages of printed output. The first program I
wrote for my self was [Conway's game of
life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life), which
got me an official warning when I picked up the output of running the
program on the
[R-pentomino](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/R-pentomino) (the output
was cut of at 100 pages of folding line printer paper and the admins
could not fail to notice this unusual amount of paper output for
single job for a first year student). One of the worst things that could happen to you in those days, was that the elastic band that kept the punch cards of your program together, would break.

At University I worked with  Algol 68, APL (from which my dislike
for the *write only* family of programming languages), Lisp. I got
interested in microprocessors, particularly liked the 6809
architecture: it was the
first microprocessor with SEX (an instruction for sign-extending an 8 bit value to 16
bit). I played my first interactive computer game on my friends
Sinclair (Timex) ZX80: you would run around a maze trying to find an
exit, or until a dinosaur blocked your way and you lost.

I co-founded and chaired the Dutch Hobby-Computer-Club chapter for
Motorola 68000 processors. However I did not have the money to buy a
full fledged 68000 system like the [Apple
Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lisa). So I settled for a
6502 based BBC Micro computer and wrote a cross assembler in BASIC
that allowed me to upload
programs to my, self-soldered, 68000 board (with 4K ROM and 4K RAM!).
The BBC first had a cassette-tape (some programs were broadcast on
Dutch radio that you could record and upload to your system), later a
floppy drive (2x100Kb per 5.25" disc. Apart from Basic and 6502 assembler the BBC allowed me to try Forth, BCPL, MicroProlog and Pascal.

I went to University and an early age and that had kept me out of the draft for military service, but by
the time I started studying Japanese I was older and should have done that service
first. Of course this was found out and I got drafted on very, very,
short notice. I was not very happy in the service, among other things because I could
not find a place to meditate, like I was used to do every morning. I was
stationed at the Tonnet Kazerne military base "'t Harde" where in the
classroom next to where I was, an AP-23 mine (which had the colouring
of an instruction mine, but was a real one) exploded, killing [the
instructor and six of my
collegues](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lijst_van_Nederlandse_rampen#1980-1989). Afterwards I
asked our commander how to get out of the army in an
interview, and I was told to apply as an conscientious objector. I applied as such and was back
being a civilian within 24 hours. I think they were glad to have one
less person with potential trauma to worry about.

I did not make sense too much to continue studying full time, because,
as conscientious objector, I would soon have to do public service for
18 months (1.5 times the length of the military service). Public service
normally involved something like changing bedding in a hospital or home
for the elderly, but I was lucky.

First I landed a temporary job as a
Basic programmer and sysadmin on a PDP-11 using multi-user basic under
[RT-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RT-11). I wrote software for
pupils to learn basic math and fill out blanks with correct words in
sentences. That system was about to be upgraded to Xenix, and I had to
program in Pascal (and some parts in C), translating the Basic
programs by hand at high speed. At the same time I started to use
curses instead of the programmed in escape sequences used to move the
cursor on the 6 different (second hand) serial line based CRT terminals we
were using. The PDP had 8" floppys for making backups, I still have
some adhesive labels for those, if someone needs them.

The software development was a university project and when I told the
director I could not sign on for a longer period because of my work as
a conscientious objector, he made arrangements so that I could
continue to do the same work as fulfilment of that requirement. The software development and 
sysadmin work was way better than any other work I could have hoped for, but the
(prescribed) pay level was about a fifth of my previous pay for the same job.  Therefore I
worked a bit on the side selling computers. My company name: "Antron",
as tacky as it gets, but which I thought a cool name at the time.

By 1984 I had a 300 baud modem at home, and was the only student in
our student housing (170 rooms) having a private phone. The modem was hooked
up to my BBC micro running Kermit. I continued studying, but combining
Japanese with work was difficult. I switched to master in General
Linguistics, which allowed me to include courses like "computability"
and "formal languages and automata" in my general linguistics master program. Those courses were held at the now opened computer
science faculty, the CS
students didn't understand why a guy would do such subjects out of his
own volition.

Before I could pick-up some speed in my studies again, some friends
from my high-school asked me to join a start-up. In that company we
instructed students at the Academy of Architecture in Amsterdam in the
use of computers and ran a laboratory for specialised computer usage
(with an A0 plotter etc.). I co-wrote a 3D modelling program running
on Atari ST and IBM PC AT (Autocad was still 2.5D only). And I
modified my Atari ST: it had more available memory (by piggy-backing
memory chips, soldering all but one pin to the existing 16 memory
chips); it had the processor de-soldered  (60+ pins, not so easy) and
replaced by it a socket, in which I put a board with the original
processor, a PAL based address selector and a 68881 floating point
coprocessor; and on the ROM module I installed a modified C't design
with dual ISA slots (on a read only bus!). In the ISA slots I had a IBM PGA graphics board.

Our software was in Modula-2 and I rewrote the software floating point
library to use the 68881 math coprocessor and rewrote part of the library calling the GEM based graphics driver to redirect to the PGA. That way we could generate images much faster than on a
the PC, with significantly larger models (but rendering was still far from real-time).

For our
first real walk-through we drove an IBM monitor which was fixed to a 2
meter long board, and shot images with a film camera that was adapted for single shot
recording on the other side of the board (triggered by the Atari once
an image was ready). After running for 2 days and developing the film
we found that the CRT monitor had overheated (because of the cardboard casing that was there to keep the light out) and that the monitor had gone
completely off-color.....

During that time (late 80s) I also published
my first open source contribution in a magazine (an optimized
quick-sort implementation in Modula-2)

We switched to a separate Z-buffer based renderer after I had
calculated that with the number of polygons we were handling (we did back to front
painting on the hardware accelerated PGA board), that Z-buffer
would be more efficient. We needed to store the resulting images, and
GIF was selected as there was software from CompuServe to show these
images on MSDOS computers with various graphics boards, as well as a program from IBM to show these on their PS/2
systems (which IBM had donated to the Academy). However there was no
program to go from software frame buffer to GIF, so I reverse
engineered that, with the help of the original article on LZW
compression and checking the output against the two viewers that we
had.  Once that was done I also wrote our own viewer for the special
graphics boards that were becoming available for AutoCAD (already at
that time the GPU was often more powerful than the PC the board was
put into). This was all done in Zortech C++.  On the PC we had a
minimal program (1.5Kb) to switch from renderer to viewer and back, so the viewing code did not take valuable memory (always at a premium on the PC). I
had not been in England that often and I called the viewing program
'shower.exe' as it *show*ed our images. The guy reviewing our manuals
had a hard time, as he, as a native speaker of English, had difficulty not to associate "shower"
with a bathroom activity.

We tried to speed things up using Transputers and parallel processing
at some time, but this was quite difficult. Occam, a nice language
with indentation as indication of block structure (like Python), was a far call from C and
Modula-2. Things looked much better when I tried the Transputer under
[Helios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeliOS) (a Unix like OS) on the [system Atari
developed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_Transputer_Workstation), but unfortunately that never took of commercially.

The Academy bought two Sun machines, which were fast, except that the
FPU did not do square roots (as did the 68881) in hardware. And we
needed square rooting a lot in our software for vector
normalisation. Since the vectors multiplied were limited in input
values because of they were already normalized, I figured out we could
use a 1024 entry lookup table of floating point values. which nicely
speeded up calculations by an order of magnitude. The Sun machines
brought me back to using Unix and I have worked on Unix on a daily
basis since then (1990).

The shower program was much wanted by graphic board manufacturers
(SPEA, ELSA, Artist Graphics, etc. all with proprietary hardware as
well as several VESA manufacturers). That was because we had
**architectural** images that showed very well on their 256 colour
graphic boards. Their alternative were dithered GIF images based on
photos of scantily (if at all) clad women, not always a good thing to
use on trade shows.  Adapting the back-end of the "shower" to a new
board was a matter of routine after the first few that I did. I used
to visit the companies to have access to the latest (unreleased)
hardware and had several experiences of managers not believing they
work was finished in good cooperation with their engineers within an
hour or two.

By now we were using DOS-extender on 386 and while visiting Artist
Graphics, the spare time (I had flown to Dublin for 2 days, just in
case things would take longer) was put to good use. After adapting the
rendering program to map in the Z buffer in the high-memory mapped
graphics board space I could see the rendering taking place in real
time at an acceptable resolution. This slowed down the rendering
slightly, but made it much more easy for us to see where the rendering
process went wrong (if it did). Once SPEA found out, they did not want
to be outdone by the competition and we got an Intel 860 based board
from them, on which we could do the whole rendering, and see the
progress and it was faster than the state of the art 386 PC in which
the board was inserted.

Our single shot camera was exchanged for a videorecorder (rollback,
roll forward, take a single shot, roll back ....) and a targa/vista
graphics board (without file format description, but that was an easy
one to figure out). Some very nice video walkthroughs resulted from that.

However the technical successes were not followed by enough sales and
investor money disappeared as in a black hole. I sold my shares, and
decided to use the money to finish my long postponed thesis. For the
research I used my
386 machine and dos-extender to run the text analysis programs. It
ran in an hour what the VAX machine at the Linguistics Institute could
only do in several days (the difference being mainly due to the whole
dictionary of words fitting in memory on the 16Mb RAM of the 386, so
lookups of word associated codes were much faster than on the VAX
where this had to come from disc repeatedly, as it had only 256Kb
memory and that shared with the processes the others ran).

At that time I also still had my Atari ST, often used by friends for
typesetting papers and thesis'. I had been using LaTeX since the mid
80s. Fortunately laser-printers became available, until that time I had
printed LaTeX output on my 9 needle STAR printer, going over each line
three (3!) times, I normally switched on the printer in the evening
and went to sleep somewhere else if I had to print more than 4
pages. I also helped set the book on Generative Grammar by one of my
professors and earned the gratitude of several people by converting
Word documents close to the deadline of submission, documents that
Microsoft Word would no longer render in any acceptable way (after an
image was inserted, or a table of contents requested).

With my thesis finished, I started as manager at the other 3D graphics
software company in Amsterdam. The software there ran on SGI Iris, DEC
Ultrix and on Sun, later also on HPUX and on Linux (mid 90s).  The
software was a solid modeller and ray-tracer with all kinds of modules
for NURBS, blobs and particles as extensions. I did not program much
as a manager but I kept an eye on the process and the revision control
system.  The program was in K&R C, parts of the interface in TCL and
an internally developed functional language called Intercol was used
for specification of surface "materials' and also for interactive
interface design. When I took over the management of the project, one
of the features of Intercol was that there was no normal way of
documenting the software by inserting comments (the developer said
that if you really needed comments, you could just write a conditional
that was never true with a string in the non-evaluated part of the
conditional acting as some form of documentation...).

We had 50 DEC Ultrix machines in the basement (an expensive
heat source) for parallel rendering, each with 16Mb of memory, but
enough swap-space on disc (storage was on the network). Unfortunately
the users of the system (some extremely creative art students) did
rather want to use scanned images for textures (so they knew what it
would look like) than try and write some (Intercol) program that might
approached the visual effect of what they wanted. The memory
consumption was by these images was huge as our software memory mapped
the images and the rendering machine spent most of its time on
swapping. My main software development contribution in that time was
to write a Targa to tiled TIFF converter and then a caching mechanism
for those tiles in the renderer. That way we did not need to read in
the multi-megabyte images in memory completely. Because of the way the
ray-tracer used the pixels from these images (mostly requiring pixels
from the image close to each other) this helped speed things up a
lot. This immediately prompted the students to use much finer detail
images (read: higher resolution), but fortunately the tiling mechanism still
worked out fine for those as well.

Here was also the first time I had to work with HTML in setting up the
first website I was involved in (late 1993). Some of my new employees had
introduced me to Python (which they had used at the CWI in Amsterdam
where Guido van Rossum was begin employed). I liked the design of that
language, but did not want a fourth language in our software. So it
took a few years before I actually did something with that.

In the mid 90s I spent two years in the USA, where I managed the
development of a multimedia database and associated front-end. Warner
Brothers, The Discovery Channel and Spielberg (his Survivors of the
Shoah project) were among our customers. During that time I was
almost exclusively involved with SGI (and IRIX) which was approaching
the top of their dominance in the graphics market. I also had my first
off-shore development team (to port the front-end to the Mac), with
often broken email communication to Bangalore that was not a very
successful experience.

After moving back to Europe, I started working in Las Palmas de Gran
Canaria, (voted best place to live before San Diego and Casablanca). We
would work in the morning, have lunch at 2pm, visit Las Canteras beach
until five, shower and then work until nine. I was still doing graphics,
this time editing and compositing software on SGI. Unfortunately that was
only a year  of employment to get the development organised.

One thing I will never forget is that we had 10base2 (coaxial)
Ethernet at the office in Las Palmas. Twice a week the workstations of
the developers could not reach each other or the server because the
cleaners would have swiped the floor and touched one of the Ethernet
transceivers, breaking the loop. Finding where the loop was broken
often took an hour. The company had money for SGI Indigo2 machines but
had not invested in a better network, so until we could get something
faster I used an unused 10baseT hub (unused because it was 110V for
use on trade shows) and telephone cable and RJ45 connectors to hook
the machines up and discard large tracts of the cheapernet that had of
course become very expensive because of the downtime.

Because the founder of the company was afraid of people remotely
accessing our computers and steal the software, we had no internet
connection to our desktop like I was used to, and we also had no
email. I convinced the owner that the "old" way of doing emails would
really be safe enough and one spare Personal Iris system was set up
with a dial-out modem to pick up and sent emails. That system was
connected to another machine in our network using a serial port.  UUCP
(initiated from the internal network) was used to communicate the
emails. At least that way we could just write and receive emails at
our own desk. The revision control system I had set up while I was in
Las Palmas, was still operating after 12 years, when I did help the
company to upgrade to mercurial.

I would come back to Las Palmas but not after spending two years on
something completely different: Applying the lessons learned in the
software development process on molecular nanotechnology (there are
parallels, as both engineering activities require little in the form
of raw material, resulting in less careful design). I invested (and
lost) most of my savings on that project, but it was fun. That although
Brussels was a dreary place, especially after sunny Gran Canaria.

In Brussels I had ISDN, and set up my first Linux based machine at
home as a workstation and router (for my and my wifes laptops). The
server was SuSE based, as ISDN was popular in Germany and SuSE had
stable ISDN support out of the box.

Also during that time I started developing software in Python, which
quickly became my favourite language for non-time-critical jobs.  I did
part-time development work after my son was born, while my wife was
travelling over Europe (helping her customers with ISO 9000
certification, I was supporting those customers with browser and
Python based software solutions). I contributed to some open source
projects (implemented new string matching specifications in
file/magic, packaged the ReiserFS software into RPMs before it was
part of the normal distributions). Since then I have made
contributions on a regular basis for many a project that I needed to
improve for my own use.  During that time (1999/2000) I also put a
second Pentium III in my computer to calculate the 196 palindrome
problem to 10 million places (John Walker of Autodesk fame had gone to
1 million a few years earlier on a Sun machine).

With a second child on its way I moved back to the USA to do some more
serious (and above all serious money making) work. I just managed to
hit the dot-com crash at the end of 2000, but found another job, had
to fly back because of visa issues but finally everything got resolved
before the money ran out. I first managed a small development group in
Sausalito (CA) making compositing software (used by ILM for the
StarWars movies). I was returning to Windows and Mac for development,
but I had Linux based machines for revision control. My personal
system was a Win98 based Sony laptop, that ran SuSE under VMware. So
Outlook Express would read the emails via IMAP from the SuSE based
IMAP server. Later I switched to a DELL D800 and ran it natively under
Linux with a Windows VM for compatibility (you learn when OpenOffice
mangles your bosses Word document).

By 2004 I had set up the engineering in most of the companies 10+
engineering locations in 5 countries (a result of acquisitions). It
used replication of compiled libraries, a whole development method
around that, remotely triggered builds and tests. The most
problematic group was in Germany and I (was) moved there to make sure
they got integrated in the process. Unfortunately our company was
sold, and the promises for my position in Germany over time were not
kept by the new management. Apart from that, the new mother company
had 4 engineers for maintaining ClearCase, where I had supported the
CVS/cvsup based revision control (later mercurial) for all locations
remotely on my own and next to my normal management responsibilities
for several products. I certainly did not see it as a career move to
learn ClearCase and work on that full-time. Politics started playing
up as well as some other indigestible management decisions, so I decided to
work as a freelancer again, which I have done since then.

**Where I am now**

I would say at least 25 of the 30 years I have been professionally
involved in software development, I have been working on some sort of
Unix or Linux. Initially with `csh`, then `ksh` (Sun IIRC), `tcsh` (on
Irix) and now 
`bash`. I like the maintainability of Python (I share much of
Eric S. Raymonds experience with fetchmail in that respect 
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882).) and switch from `bash`
to using Python before the quotes and its syntax start to irritate me. I
know how to use `sed`, but never bothered much with awk, essentially because
I can do anything that would require awk in Python (I'm not saying
Python is better, but I am certainly better **at** Python).

SuSE was problematic after Novell's takeover, it landed me with
inaccessible support pages and all kinds of problems not good for
persoal use of Linux, unacceptable for professional use. I attended
the Ubuntu delopment conference in Paris (2006) and switched first
myself and then the company, 15 machines or so, to Ubuntu. Currently I
am running 12.04 (in classic mode) and I am considering switching to
Linux Mint full time as I really don't like the direction the default
Ubuntu UI has taken.

I never was a full time adminstrator of Unix or Linux, but the last 15
years I did 
delve into many things U&L related and contributed when
possible. ReiserFS, mdadm, LUKS encrypted `/home`, sendmail, postfix,
bind, Apache & mod_wsgi, file/magic, spamassassin, IMAP, all have
taken their fair share of my attention (as did several not direcly U&L
related projects, such as implementing the [ordereddict libary in C for
Python](http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/Python/ordereddict/)).

On U&L I am more inclined to be a reviewer than that I have broad
knowledge of U&L issues (maybe that is my managerial role showing
itself). I like the U&L atmosphere, and even though I sometimes
(necessarily) get corrected by the experts here, I think I make my
contribution.

Outside of U&L I am online active on Khan Academy, where I refreshed my
rusty math skills ( https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/avdn/ ) and try
to keep a good Energy Points and Badges earned score.

I am a board member of the [EuroPython
Society](http://www.europython-society.org/), that is responsible for
the EuroPython conferences.

When I'm not at my PC (it happens) I can be found in the local dojo,
training Shotokan Karate (I got my nidan in 2014). If you are stuck in
software problem and want some distraction there is nothing like a
fist that is quickly approach your face, to get back to reality.

Since I don't watch TV all, that still leaves me time to cook 
for my daughter (who lives with me) and my girlfriend on a daily basis
(and bake bread because the Germans don't know how to do that).

Timeline/location:

```
1961 -> Netherlands 1994 -> Ohio/California 1996 -> 
Gran Canaria 1997 -> Brussels 1999 -> Gran Canaria 2000 -> 
San Francisco -> 2001 Gran Canaria 2001 -> Sausalito (CA) 
2004 ->  Braunschweig, Germany
```

Answer (score 11):

My first computer was running OS/2; I was probably the last one in my class to get one. So as you may already guess I have never used any version of Windows as my regular OS.

My first contact with Linux was buying SuSE 5.1(?). I did not intend to use it; I just wanted to have a look at it because I had heard about it again and again. From an OS/2 perspective that was a "seen, laughed, deleted" experience. Not very attractive to someone who doesn't know what a mount point is (and has noone for asking). I kept on laughing about the Linux desktops for quite a while but became jealous of the process killing capabilities. Then IBM's PowerPC disaster killed OS/2's perspective (maybe just accelerated the inevitable). I switched to Linux at SuSE 7.x and used KDE (SuSE's default desktop.

Later I somehow got in touch with the [Berlin Linux User Group (BeLUG)](http://www.belug.de/) and helped organize the Berlinux 2005, a small Linux fair at the Berlin Institute of Technology (where I was studying management and computer science). Then I lost contact to BeLUG for several years. At that time I started becoming familiar with cryptography (the usage part not the math). For a few years I was very active in a political party and tried to get this party "more interested" in Linux and crypto. Not very successfully as you may have guessed.

Then fate kicked in: I got in contact with someone at BeLUG via Facebook(!)... In autumn 2012 I started giving regular crypto courses at BeLUG. In theory for the general public but IIRC we never had participants from the outside. I created offline mainkeys for my participants. Manually in the console. What a pain (though it didn't really feel like it at that time).

By the end of 2012 I created http://www.openpgp-schulungen.de/ - the first of now several crypto-related web sites by me. This web site should help others to give similar courses (on a high technical level).

Then fate **really** kicked in: Edward Snowden happened. It took even me several days to recognize the impact of this event. Cryptoparty existed at this point but was a tiny event hardly anyone cared about. Because the Berlin Cryptoparty people did not allow the TV people to shoot at their events, the TV people all came to me... Until then I did not call my courses "Cryptoparty" because I don't like several aspects of the Cryptoparty attitude. In July 2013 BeLUG introduced a weekly crypto course (for OpenPGP and XMPP-OTR) which lasted about a year and has been reduced to an about monthly event afterwards.

I March 2014 I started participating in the regular meetings of Berlin's computer science teachers (twice a year). At the four events in 2014 and 2015 I gave crypto courses there. In November 2014 I started a project (together with the former head of this teacher association) for getting regular crypto courses at schools. Although there were several interested teachers and we met a couple of times this was a complete failure. I consider this very unfortunate because it should be quite easy and very effective to have such (voluntary) courses at schools.

In spring or summer 2013 I created http://www.crypto-fuer-alle.de/. Until today this web site is (to my knowledge) the biggest collection of organizational and technical suggestions for spreading (and improving) crypto. Most of it is in German, though.

In April 2014 I started giving regular crypto courses at Berlin's Free University, mainly for computer science students. With the exception of the first event in a semester (which was part of the introduction events for the new students) we never had a lot of participants. After about a year this activity has heen reduced to one or two events per year.

2014, 2015, and 2016 I was elected to the board of BeLUG. Until 2014 Berlin had Germany's biggest Linux event (LinuxTag) in which BeLUG has been participating more or less from the beginning (in Berlin). After the LinuxTag 2014 several people at BeLUG were of the opinion that this event was not well suited for getting new Linux users. This was not criticism: I am not even sure whether the LinuxTag ever considered this as an important target group. Thus we thought about what kind of event we would like to have as an addition to the LinuxTag. The (probably) [first public appearance of this idea](http://www.heise.de/forum/Open-Source/News-Kommentare/LinuxTag-faellt-2015-aus/Was-fuer-Veranstaltungen-brauchen-wir/posting-3166637/show/) was in October 2014 after the LinuxTag had been cancelled for 2015. This was a bit embarrassing for Berlin which made the start of the revolution easier.

On BeLUG's Christmas party 2014 we talked about this with people from Berlin's other big LUG. And on BeLUG's next general meeting (in January 2015) we officially decided to give this a try. At that time not even the name was fixed. This became "Linux Presentation Day" soon after; not very German but we did not want to solve a German problem but a (as we thought) worldwide problem and didn't consider it helpful to use a name which had to be translated.

The basic idea (explained in more detail on [the international web site](http://www.linux-presentation-day.org/)) is

1. to have lots of quite small (and thus easily and cheaply organized) events so that more or less every group (does not even have to be a registered association) is capable of acting as host
2. to make so many cities participate in this regular (twice per year) event that we get coverage in the nationwide non-IT media.

There are some nice side effects like we help potential organizers get the necessary resources (people, room, computers) and support them with digital and (free) printed material. Similarly we hel people found new Linux user groups.

This concept really had an impact. We started in May 2015 with 8 locations (limited to Berlin). In November 2015 we had (after many cancellations!) 79 locations in 72 cities in three countries (Germany, Austria, and Switzerland, of course). The next event, on April, 30th 2016, will probably have about 100 cities in Germany alone and at least 8 involved European countries (among them the five biggest). Thus I really expect this to become the Linux revolution. We guess that between 1% and 10% of the Windows users is interested in having a look at Linux and can imagine switing to Linux (if it turns out usable). Being mentioned twice per year in nationwide media many more people will hear about Linux and consider having a look at it. I consider it possible that from 2017 or 2018 we may get about 1% of the computer users per year to Linux. 1% does not sound like much and I guess that at least the 1% of Windows users who are most easy for us to get already hate Windows... But 1% means about 500,000 people per year in Germany. I guess BeLUG (with its current resources and organization) can easily help about 100 people per year to install Linux. Compare that to 20,000 per year in Berlin. Thus the expected success may be difficult to handle. Fortunately the adult education centers are very interested in the Linux Presentation Day (and lots of future customers).

After being the one who had the idea I am currently the only real organizer for the Linux Presentation Day for Berlin (i.e. beyond one location), Germany and Europe. So you can indeed say that this is my own revolution... :-)  BTW: We have to wait for the real results but a few hours ago terdon became active (after I pointed out the LPD to him in UL chat) which probably just made Greece the next LPD country.

Comment: Very interesting answer, Hauke. Thank you for writing. But don't forget to add something with regard to "tell the community their motivation for participating on this site".

Answer (score 10):

I've been using Linux-based systems since '05, I think Ubuntu 5.04 was my first. I remember having it delivered [via Shipit on CDs](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aUbuntu_5.04-x86.gif) since at the time I used dial-up internet. It wasn't much, but it saved me when Windows broke the day before I needed to print a large homework assignment.

I eventually dumped Windows when I realized I didn't really need it and that my occasional needs were satisfied by running it in a virtual machine.

Since then I have moved to other distros, but I mostly use Debian and Arch Linux and have other systems in virtual machines. Unfortunately those days I don't really have much time to tinker with stuff.

My background is in electrical/electronics engineering, mostly as an embedded developer (not on embedded Linux, sadly, I keep myself to small microcontrollers) and doing some signal processing work on the side (mostly MATLAB, but moving to Python).

I frequent this site since I find its quality to be quite high both in terms of questions and answers: bad questions/answers tend to be eliminated through downvotes and duplicates get closed, unlike quite a few Linux/UNIX forums where the same questions are repeated many times and often get low-quality answers. I found this site when I asked something on Stack Overflow, saw a link to here and got interested.

The other SE site I visit often is electronics.stackexchange, but mostly as a reader since my skills in electronics aren't as good as the skills of other people there.

I guess that's it for now...

Answer (score 10):

I've been using UNIX since 1993 and Linux since June 19, 1995.  I was a hardcore Linux user and a prosperous dot-com worker during the late 1990s tech boom.  When the dot-com party ended, I went to Mexico to learn Spanish, came back to the US to get my degree, and then lived in Mexico for a few years.

It was just before the dot-com party ended when I started writing my big open source program: [MaraDNS](http://maradns.samiam.org/).  During this time, I let go of my Linux fanaticism while in Mexico and started dual-booting.

As I was getting married, I realized I could not support myself developing open source, so I finished up my open source project (which I still maintain) and am now seeing how I can best monetize my years of Linux and UNIX scripting and development experience.

I am here because of a [New Year's resolution](http://samiam.org/blog/2014-01-01.html) I made to only be part of online communities which can help me be more prosperous; I answer here because I enjoy being here and to show to potential employers how skilled I am in Linux and other UNIX clones.

Comment: Since you're new I'd like to formally welcome you to U&L. I think you'll find that the ppl here are all friendly and of the SE sites I've frequented this is the one I choose to call "home" b/c they are. You'll also find some of the brightest minds to boot. I read your resolutions and I wish you luck in achieving them. I too have kids and started here for similar reasons, actually at the beginning of last year 8-). I've been on the site a long time but only used it in a readonly mode. Here's to us both continuing to use it in read/write.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  This is my favorite place in the stackexchange webspace ; it's a good friendly community.

Answer (score 10):

## Who I am

What drives me is knowledge & challenge.

When I first started with Linux, the challenge was figuring it out, learning out all the pieces worked. Now, that's become simple, and my challenge has changed to figuring things out that nobody has tried before.
But one component of the challenge that always has been, and always will be, is making things beautiful. There are few things I hate more than an ugly design. When something in Linux is done right, it works efficiently, doesn't easily break, and is easy to understand.

But the challenge thing things extends to more than just computers. I'm quite happy to tackle an ordinary puzzle :-). I've never been a big gamer. I've played video games sure, and I still do (Team Fortress 2), but they're not a big interest.

I've got Linux everwhere. At home I've got a NAS server, a general server, a router, several Raspberry Pis, couple laptops, and a desktop all running Linux (plus an Android phone, and head unit in my car). I stopped using Windows entirely around 2010.

Outside of the computer world, I love the outdoors. I moved to Florida because of the weather. I'm dead serious. I love being warm. I also love thunderstorms, and rain. Then there's the beach as well.
I enjoy kiteboarding, flying stunt kites, and frisbee. I also like hiking, and roller blading. Do a lot of reading too, but what computer geek doesn't.

## Why I'm here on Unix & Linux

All my Linux knowledge came from the community. Whether it be open source software, a man page, an IRC chat room, or a message board, almost everything I know about Linux came freely from other people. Where I am at today would not be possible without that.

**I believe in free knowledge.**

So, I want to give that to other people.
But of course I don't know everything, and so I often enjoy solving the problems people post here. So I'm also here to continue my quest for knowledge.

## My history

I actually had to trim this section down, as it was originally about three times as long, and I decided to spare you :-)

### Introduction to computers

I first started with computers back around 1994. It was a Hewlett Packard 486DX 33hz, with a whopping 16mb ram, a 300mb hard drive, and a 28.8kbps ISA modem (add on), running Windows 3.11.
I had used other computers before that, but they were things other people owned, and I never really used them much. But when my family got our own, I was immediately hooked. I just found it fascinating, and wanted to figure out how it worked.

Nothing really spectacular for the next several years. Did a lot of messing around with computers. Parents got me my own so I'd stop breaking theirs. But still using Windows.
My first one I built used a 366mhz Celeron.

### Foray into Linux

Around the same time I built my first computer (late 1998), my father recommend I look into Linux. At this point I had no clue what Linux was. The only time I'd ever heard of Linux/UNIX was in the movie [Jurassic Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/) when Lex goes "It's a UNIX system, I know this".

So I ordered a Debian CD (yes, I actually mail ordered a CD for a few dollars), and tried installing it. I tried several times actually. All of them complete disasters. It had no friendly installer, just this thing where you selected the packages you wanted to install. I had absolutely no clue what LILO was, and why I'd want it.
In fact it was such a disaster, I gave up and went back to Windows.

Then a couple months later I was at a friend's house, and saw his PC was running not-windows. Turns out, it was Linux, specifically Mandrake. So I got a hold of Mandrake, and tried it instead.
This time it went much better. Mandrake had a nice GUI installer, and I was dropped into Gnome.

For the next several years, I played around with various distributions. SUSE, Debian (once I knew more, it got another shot), Slackware, & Gentoo. But during all this I was still dual-booting Windows. I still needed access to things that couldn't be done in Linux.
In fact I never gave up Windows entirely until around 2009. There were times when I'd have multiple machines, some of them dedicated to Linux, but I always had a Windows machine around somewhere. Though mostly this was because of work. But we're jumping way too far ahead.

#### Settling into Gentoo

So we're in 2002 right now. As mentioned, I played around with several distributions, but then I tried Gentoo, and was hooked.

At first I thought I liked Gentoo because it was [supposedly faster compiling everything yourself](http://funroll-loops.info/). But eventually I realized I liked it because it gave me control. I liked building my system from scratch, and knowing everything everything that went into it (plus other reasons, but that's irrelevant). This also provided me with a lot of knowledge about how Linux works.

To this day, I still use Gentoo as my primary OS.

### Job

I Started my first Linux job in 2007 as a NOC tech. Basically monitoring systems and responding to alerts. Wasn't long before I was transferred onto the UNIX team, and there began my career in Linux.

These days I'm the system architect for cloud.com (division of Citrix Systems). Most of my work revolves around cloud computing, automation, and clustering (high availability, cluster filesystems, distributed computing, etc).

[image: Automation theory]

I believe in automating everything, thus I am very fond of scripting. I am fluent in shell script, perl, ruby, and unfortunately PHP (I was young once). I also know enough C to be able to code decently, but it's not something I do often.

I've worked with a lot of technologies. Solaris, FreeBSD, MySQL, Postgresql, Oracle, Bind, Postfix, OpenVPN, StrongSwan, Apache, Nginx, HAProxy, IPVS, IPTables, GlusterFS, Heartbeat, Pacemaker, Corosync, NIS, LDAP, to name a few.
But the things I work with and enjoy the most are:

- Bash (general scripting, and ZSH for my personal shell)
- VIM (`set -o vi` and readline vi mode everywhere!)
- Puppet (for configuration management)
- Ruby (more advanced scripting & working with Puppet)
- High availability (load balancing, automatic recovery, etc)
- Networking (DOS prevention, WAN routing, VPNs)
- Virtualization/Containerization (Cloud computing & Docker)

Comment: Thanks for writing, Patrick. And no need to make your answer short on our account. :-)

Comment: Glad to have you here, nice to know your background in addition to your solid answers 8-)

Answer (score 9):

I'm a curious geek that works in IT Systems and network security. 
I started computing on Windows 3.1 when I was 5, then I switched to Windows 95, then Millenium, and  since then I have tried to find a way out of the Microsoft way of mind. Lots of time later I finally found Ubuntu, Centos and now AIX.
I have two university diploma in France (yes I'm French), and I have been actively working for one year now.

I have been around first on Stack Overflow because I was a developer, then I discovered the magic of sysadmin and network security, and so I quit the developer World.

Since I have at the moment one of the most boring jobs ever (working in a recycling factory during summer was more attractive) I try to learn and help the maximum number of persons on the system I like: Linux.

If you want my resume you can have it; it's not hard to find, and if you want to know me better, I'm not on any social network except the professional one and Stack Exchange, which I consider as one of the nicest invention since the sundial.

More seriously, thanks for reading, see you around.

Answer (score 9):

#### Why I'm here on Unix.SE?

You can consider computing on **GNU/Linux** as one of my hobbies/interests. Especially I'm fascinated with the `command-line`! And I believe [software freedom](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/) is ethical. You may know the contribution of GNU in developing Free/Libre operating system and that of FSF in supporting the freedom.

So, Technically+Ethically GNU/Linux became my area of interest and finally computing with GNU/Linux lead me to this community.

#### Computing History:

- The education system of my state board used to add "computer" as one subject in the syllabus of 8<sup>th</sup> standard, 11 years ago;  when working with Windows Explore, Microsoft Office and basic HTML had been taught in the high-school. JavaScript, C language, Open Office and basic commands of Linux had been taught in the higher-secondary. So, during high-school I was not aware of what forms the operating system or what's Linux but I liked learning HTML which was interesting. While I was in higher-secondary I had got a Desktop computer (with Windows XP) at my home and enjoyed learning JavaScript. Though working with some basic commands of Linux had been taught theoretically but I couldn't practice that at my home since I hadn't GNU/Linux installed on my PC and actually I was not much aware what is Linux at all! (Because it was very hard to find even a single person using operating system other than Windows in my area)
- However I was always curious to experience (what's called) Linux. In early of 2013 when I was in 1st year of college [note that my field of study has nothing to do with computer] I got one copy of Ubuntu 10.10 from my friend which I tried to install on my PC. I was not aware with setting up mount point properly but out of curiosity I anyhow tried to install that Ubuntu and accidentally formatted whole the Hard-disk (lost the data) and finally I was having Ubuntu 10.10 alone living in my PC! (of-curse I re-installed Windows in a day).
- Later on we purchase a dongle/net-setter to have a dialup connection and Internet at home. I started to learn about Linux and found that there are many distributions and among them Ubuntu is recommended for new-users. I went to ubuntu.com and downloaded latest LTS i.e Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and properly installed on separate partition and then I used to have dual boot (XP & Ubuntu) successfully. I was very happy that I'm now running something other than Windows! Then I learned many things regarding using Ubuntu, I joined AskUbutu and my learning considerably enhanced.(So, having Internet connection played important role in learning Linux)
- I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Xfce Desktop Environment and enjoyed learning of Debian package-management as well as text processing with grep, tr, cut, sed etc in mid of 2014. Soon I found that I'm one of the [GNU users who never heard of GNU](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/gnu-users-never-heard-of-gnu.html). I became aware with GNU project, and liked the [Philosophy of the GNU Project](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.html). I came to know the requirement of Linux-Libre and list of distributions [endorsed by FSF](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html). I migrated to Trisquel GNU/Linux-Libre 7.0 LTS on 28th Nov. 2014 because I felt that's something like *Freebuntu*. Then I also learned about software licenses in 2015. You may see [my answer on Open Source Stack Exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/907/296). Visit my computing post at [wordpress](https://deepppandya.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/how-i-do-my-computing/).
- In 2017, during post graduation, I purchased a Dell Laptop (which came with Windows 10) on which I installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS (because I was not sure whether GPU and wireless hardware supported by Trisquel, Yes I needed to install non-free drivers and firmware to make wifi and nvidia graphics working). Meanwhile on the Desktop computer, I replaced the outdated Windows XP with Windows 7 and after long waiting upgraded to Trisquel 8 LTS in 2018.
- In March 2019, I decided to switch to Debian GNU/Linux on my laptop. So, I replaced Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with **Debian 9.8 Stretch** and upgraded to Debian 10 when it was released. Earlier I used to prefer GNONE Desktop Environment but now I have been using KDE Plasma for last 9 months.
- I run [PureOS](https://www.pureos.net/) replacing Trisquel on Desktop computer.
- Late 2020 onwards: I use **Debian** GNU/Linux (Stable Version) with MATE Desktop Environment on both machines (Desktop PC and Laptop)

### Why Unix & Linux Stack Exchange!

As I've elaborated in computing history, AskUbuntu is the oldest community I joined on Stack Exchange. In 2014 when I learned a lot about debian-packagement and then **text-processing and bash scripting**, I found this community be more interesting! In other words, *this is the real community of Unix & Linux experts.* (Also after migrating to Debian GNU/Linux my questions became off-topic on AskUbuntu). Quality of posts and nice moderation makes Stack Exchange communities very reliable according to me.

Thanks.

---

Who am I?

I think this may not be helpful to you because I am not a software developer/engineer or a programmer, neither my educational-study nor profession/business is relevant with Unix & Linux (or say computing in general). Actually my field of study is Mechanical/Thermal Engineering. That's why I started with *You can consider computing with GNU/Linux is one of my hobbies/interests*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Some more information about your background and what you use GNU/Linux for would be interesting. Also, some information about what you used before your switch.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Done!

Answer (score 9):

#### Why I am here

I joined Linux&Unix three months ago mostly because I am a senior sysadmin/netadmin turning devop. I also enjoy technical reading, the ocasional challenge, and learning while helping others.

#### First years

Through all my life I enjoyed tinkering with computers since my early teens, and nowadays I am a mix breed between a sysadmin, a network admin, and a little of programming.

I started very early in the summer of 1984 with a clone of the [ZX Spectrum 48K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum), the Timex 2048. The ZX Spectrum was a (relatively) low-cost 8 bit machine very popular in Europe, and particularly in the UK. It had a Zilog Z80 processor, that was pretty well known at the time.

[image: tc 2048]

Was already writing BASIC when a few months later on joined a technical school, and by xmas time was writing my first Z80 assembly programs. I learned a lot from the inner workings of this machine, and about the hardware, especially from the point of view of an assembly programmer. I still remember with fondness all the [MicroHobby Spanish magazines](http://www.microhobby.org) that I manage to get hold in their not-so-regular two week publishing schedule.

After finishing technical school, had a summer course in 1987 about Unix and C programming using HP/UX dumb terminals.

By this time I also bought my first PC/XT compatible computer, an Olivetti PC1. [image: Olivetti PC1].

#### Life as a programmer

In early 1988, got my first job as a programmer for 3 years in C and x86 assembly in the DOS era, and was always tinkering with stuff. Got contact again with the Unix world using Microsoft´s ill-fated [Xenix](http://www.softpanorama.org/People/Torvalds/Finland_period/xenix_microsoft_shortlived_love_affair_with_unix.shtml) around this time.

#### Warming up to English

By the summer of 1989, a Galician mentor I had at work lent me the whole Tolkien collection, and I read it all as my first really serious approach to English. Consequentially, I started using English more extensively. Before that, all my study materials were mostly in Spanish, which is very akin to my mother tongue.

#### Back to University

Got really tired of the numbing work as a full-time programmer and joined University at day time around 1992. During University always kept having related IT part time jobs, and tinkering with IT. Also bought a 386SX, and shortly thereafter a 486DX, that I used to run DOS and Unix SCO V at home, and later on Windows 3.11, OS/2 and Windows 95.

Done a lot of mischief, including hacking the Unix SCO V server and the Novell services at the University. Also hacked [lots of] games at home. Started also using BBSs and [Minitel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minitel) services at this time.

#### Erasmus developer project in England

In 1995, started using the Internet at the faculty, mostly HTTP and IRC. Went on as a Erasmus student to England, and wrote in Bristol as my thesis the [first emulator for Windows of the ZX Spectrum 48K](http://ruka12.tripod.com/wspecem.html), and actually the first open source emulator for Windows. That C source code was used as a pioneer concept on Windows for many emulators that followed.

Was also particularly active in [comp.sys.sinclair](http://rk.nvg.ntnu.no/sinclair/faq/) at that time, specially in rather long threads about the inner dark workings of the Z80 processor with Ian Collier.

#### First Unix sysadmin/network admin job

Upon returning in 1996, I was offered the place of the Unix system administrator of the core services of the Polytechnic Universities of my home town, Porto. I had to pickup on the network administrator tasks as there was not a network administrator. Got seriously hacked in the first year, and there were so many days and night were I was actually forced to learn security on the other side of the fence. Got there my first contacts with firewalls, exploits, security hardening, Cisco, Thin-Ethernet, UTP, switches, Ultrix, Digital Unix, HP/UX, RedHat Linux 4.0 to 6.0, Debian Linux and [NeXTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXT).

[image: at job]

Had a life changing interview at the end of my first year of work, in which I was rudely called a clown by not knowing some core Unix concepts, or rather explaining them in a way more convoluted than it was expected of me. Spent the 2nd year, besides working, using up all my waking hours reading every damn book I could find in the University library about Unix and communications, often to the tune of 3-4 books per week.

#### Life as a network, systems, and security Consultant

So in 1998, I was hired to work as a network, systems and security consultant in the best purely Portuguese consulting agency at the time. Was placed in a customer that loved my work; actually the customer told to the consulting outlet I was wasted there, in several meetings. That consulting company gave me a lot of training abroad, and I was sent to conferences in USA, Paris, London. Good old times, actually. Got here real experience with Solaris, AIX, HP/UX, OpenBSD, Debian, RedHat, Checkpoint, VPNs.

#### International Consultant

Offered myself as volunteer for International projects. Went to the first projects in Mozambique in 2000. The first one was performance analysis where I solved an huge nation-wide communication problem in an ISP; the 2nd one was designing and setting up the Internet connection and security infra-structure of the national central bank, where I dealt with Debian, Mandrake Linux, Solaris, Cisco, network design, security and Checkpoint.

#### Network Administrator

In 2003 went to work in the network team of the largest country-wide data network in my home country, Portugal; was there a year, doubling up as a Unix Solaris/Linux administrator, automating usual and regular network tasks, and setting up IDSs and Nagios.

#### One-man IT department in the largest ISP of Maputo

An opportunity came up to go to Mozambique as an expat, to keep the cable Internet running in 2004, or it was that much I was told when I was hired.
Arrived there to an empty IT department that fired themselves due to a CEO with a very strong temper, and kept the ISP running (almost) single-handled for more than a whole year, until finding people able to give me a hand.

#### Life as an expat in Africa

Never had so many hats at once: I was the IT manager, the sysadmin, the network admin, the programmer, the DNS/DHCP master, the Helpdesk manager, and the 3rd-4th line of technical support... Learned a lot in the process. Had very good days, very bad days. Managed to get along with the CEO, and whilst the project was supposed to be 1 year, I ended up being there 5 years. Also give an helping hand to the Angola department. In the first 3 years there, I do not have a doubt I was one the best of the country in what touched to systems and communications.

Used for the ISP servers Debian and FreeBSD,  and also got my fundaments of ISP inner workings (BGP, others) and large scale services.

#### Started using Macs

There, also in 2005, discovered OS/X by accident, as my CEO often asked me to fix his more strange problems, and took a liking for it to this day. (I had previous Mac contacts with OS/9). So around 2006, I started using an iMac at work, bought for my personal machine a PowerBook G4, and mandated iMacs as the standard desktops for the ISP offices.

[image: powerbook G4]

#### back home - Freelancer

Went back to my home country in 2009 due to personal reasons. While unemployed I tried to go freelancer working for local cable companies...however had problems getting paid. Did a fantastic jack of all trades job for a local cable company, where singled handed reconfigured their voIP MTAs, their modems, wrote the backend software for controlling the provisioning in the cable network, designed their redundancy system using BGP, and wrote software to capture the customer usage drinking from [NetFlow](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/ios-netflow/prod_white_paper0900aecd80406232.html).

#### Back to academia, as network / system / security administrator

At the end of this spell, I went on to work for a very prestigious local University in 2010 where I was hired for the network team, and after a year was asked to double my tasks as the Senior Linux Administrator..

The environment was quite good as managed to tinker and put hands in a lot of new technology; I also got my skills up to date with Unix/Linux using SuSE and Debian, even got myself certified. Also learnt new things, as [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com), FreeRadius ([EDUROAM](https://www.eduroam.org)), vmware, and so much more. Also had regularly trainees.

#### Back to the corporate IT world

Now in 2018, went back to the corporate world as a Linux Cloud Consultant working for the major player in the ISP industry in Portugal. Also went again using a desktop Linux machine due to being "given" a corporate Intel notebook. Using AntiX Linux on it.

#### IT hobbies at home

Nowadays at home I am tinkering with iOS, OS/X, Unix, ARM architectures and [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org). I have got a very interesting home server, a [Lamobo R1](http://lamobo.com/lamobor.html).

[image: at home]

#### Who am I

Finally to give a final personal touch to this rather lengthy professional oriented post, I am a man in my 40s, have a beautiful blond daughter born in South Africa, and currently have a Philippine wife.

I am leaving my linked.in profile [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/rui-ribeiro/16/ab8/434). I am an open networker, and I do welcome a lot contacts, especially from people on the IT field.

Comment: Very interesting answer. Thank you for writing, Rui. Note "changing life interview" is more commonly written as "life changing interview".

Comment: "Was place in a customer that loved my work, and actually the customer told to the consulting outlet several times, I was wasted there." That sentence could be better phrased, particularly the first part. And it should probably read "Was placed with".

Comment: I will go through the English later on they day, still morning here...often my mother tongue gets on the way. Will add pictures too. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Added a couple of pictures, will do something later on as the work day is starting here.

Comment: Ah the Z80, that was my favorite instruction set.

Comment: @slm I have to complement this... one of those days. Moved out of academia last year. The Z80 was a nice hobby.

Comment: I originally missed your addition, glad you added it. Glad to see others added theirs.

Comment: @slm added a few tidbits about the current situation.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a Newbie in your community.

I come from Germany. Forgive bad english, I never use it outside the school.

50 years old and pensioner without IT background. I had several physical Job's like (storekeeper, detergency), because i had no industrial training.

I bought my 1st computer 2001. After 2 months I switched from Windows XP to Linux (SuSE). Later to Debian.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

The most time I was learning by doing and out books. Then I discovered Internet. I'm a late bloomer :D

The most time I am active in a German Ubuntu-Forum.

I come here for learning and to train my brain. I am a stroke patient and I think the best way to train is to solve problems and to try learn more.

I hope I have not written any funny stuff. Leo.org is not always helpful

greeting bahamut

Comment: Hi Bahamat. Thanks for contributing an answer. This thread hasn't seen much activity lately. Debian is always a good choice. It's what a lot of us use, especially those of us that hang out in the chat room. Which hasn't been very active in recent months, but there's always room for improvement. You could join us in the room - it's https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat

Comment: Thanks for your invitation to chat

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty much a beginner to the Linux environment. I started using Linux based systems only after I got a job as a systems administrator in my school. So, I efficiently got introduced to Linux on *July 31, 2013*. From that time on, whenever I open my browser, I open 3 windows. My gmail account, my school email account and [AWESOME-O](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

The one thing I like about Linux is there are endless ways to do the same thing unlike Windows. I personally would like to thank my current job which allowed me to explore deep into many things and giving me the much needed confidence. I am not a good programmer in java which gives me creeps whenever I wanted to get an input, though I did most of my school projects in Java.  But with shell scripting, I feel the passion inside me asking to explore more and more and thus giving me the much needed confidence.

Off late, it has become an obsession for me to just browse through the questions and read the answers though occasionally I answer some of them. The wonderful thing I like about [AWESOME-O](http://unix.stackexchange.com) is, people are really helpful. I never felt discouraged here. If I answer something wrongly or ask a dumb question, instead of constant downvoting, people actually point out what aspect is wrong in the question and give me constructive criticism, which I feel is a major advantage over other stack exchange sites. It always encourages me to do my research properly before posting something bluntly.

I even have changed my career ambition from looking for a software engineer job to something more of a systems engineer job. I am pretty sure that Linux is the way to go and in the coming years.

My future goal is to contribute at least a package or fix for software bugs in Linux thus giving back something useful to the community which has always given me the best.

Comment: Tnanks for writing, but what on earth is "AWESOME-O"?

Comment: I would like to name the site as AWESOME-O :) It is just a name cartman keeps for himself, when he tries to fool butters in southpark :)

Comment: I see. I missed that pop culture reference. :-)

Comment: Ramesh, are you still at school, or do you have a job now? If so, you could say a little about the job.

Comment: I am still at school only :) I will update it once I have a job :)

Answer (score 7):

I m a linux user from 2008 and my first Linux is Ubuntu.

In 2012 I became Ubuntu Member via Ubuntu Forums.

In 2012 I started using CentOS but not much.

Since 2014 CentOS became my main Linux OS as I started my career as Linux System Administrator.

Everyday improving my skills of BASH and Python.

`Why I am here`

First I want to learn Linux not about one particular type of  OS . I want to know Linux core parts.And this is the place to learn.I found so many questions which are awesome and with excellent information.

Next I am happy with my Ask Ubuntu contribution.

So I choose this place as my new home with first preference of learning and next answering what I know.

I am Raja and I am Indian.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Raja. Thank you for writing. Can you flesh out your answer a bit? Such as why you are on this site?

Comment: I can't put this in format as I am writing this from mobile chrome browser.

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 7):

## Who am I, outside of technology?

I’m married, with three children. Two of them have special needs; the third is “typical”; a fourth survived only a day. Outside of the usual work, sleep, family & school functions, and kids’ extracurricular classes, the only other major focus of my life is jogging. It’s a “bucket list” item for me to complete a marathon (or longer!) distance. It’s simple,and I hope it keeps me healthy. Oddball interests that no longer get many time slices include: geocaching -- mainly puzzle solving and CITO (Cache-In, Trash Out) events, bicycling, reading, (indoor) rock climbing, ping-pong, soccer, motorcycling, and artificial intelligence (in game playing).

## Who am I, relative to technology?

#### Theme: I like to solve problems with computers.

### Grade School

My very first computer experiences were in early grade school with Macintoshes (Turtle Logo) and a Commodore 64, on which we could `SAVE` and `LOAD` programs to an external cassette tape. I remember going over to a friend’s house and writing my first program:

```
10 PRINT "JEFF "
20 GOTO 10
```

… and seeing my name scroll across the screen.

[image: IBM PC Convertible]

In late grade school, my Dad was able to check out an [IBM PC Convertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PC_Convertible) from the school library, ostensibly to write coursework. I quickly “took over”, asking him to check it out as frequently as possible. He ended up going back to the trusty manual typewriter, using carbon paper.

[image: Family Computing magazine]

I subscribed to [Family Computing magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Computing) and taught myself to touch-type by hand-entering programs from the appendices into the IBM PC, complete with column after column of hex data statements for the corresponding graphics and sounds.

[image: Sopwith]

That PC had a simple side-scrolling fighter-plane game called [Sopwith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sopwith_(video_game)) that I enjoyed -- particularly after I discovered that the enemy planes would regenerate in a predictable place and time, allowing me to rack up an infinite score.

Just before high school, my Mom helped me purchase my very first PC, a 286, from a local college professor. It had … a *hard drive*! Twenty MEGABYTES! Oh, you could see forever on that kind of disk! I bought caseloads of floppies from the massive [Computer Shopper Magazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Shopper_(US_magazine)). I still remember labelling disk after disk for multi-part ZIP and later ARJ archives. Those were the BBS days; when I wasn’t writing BASIC programs to play the theme song from Dallas, I spent time in games like Castle Wolfenstein 3D, Duke Nukem, Lemmings, and Chess.

### High School

[image: Slackware floppies]

[image: Slackware installation]

High school introduced me to several new cultures and friends, one of whom had his Dad’s university UNIX login credentials. This brought me the ability to download Slackware images over the Internet and `dd` them to floppy disks on the SunOS systems, one after the other after the other after the other … and then installing them back at home. Why did X11 have to be TWELVE floppies?!? Thus began my Linux experiences! I also have vivid memories of challenging classmates to see who could write the longer science class reports. I would stay up late typing in passages from every science book from the library; then anxiously listen to the dot-matrix printer chewing back and forth just before the school bus arrived. The magic of the Internet also exposed me to Usenet (comp.sys.sun.admin and the problems/summaries there), to the Lynx browser, to Netrek and to a [MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD) called OverDrive.

[image: Netrek]

[image: Overdrive MUD]

Netrek and OverDrive were both addictive -- in general because they were Internet-connected multi-player games and for their programming aspects. I used to play along with a built-in robot in Netrek, testing its behavior. I learned about the ability to program in your own ‘bot, but never made it as far as actually writing one. OverDrive was a fun place to explore the D&D realm, though I was never a “real” D&D player. It was more fun for me to learn how the system worked, and I was quickly drawn to a programmable telnet client called tinyfugue. From simple combination macros to trigger-based event handling, I expanded my client-side arsenal to include an automatic room-mapping algorithm and functions that computed “live” game statistics that were interesting to me.

High school provided a Pascal class, which was fun. I had no trouble with the exercises until the teacher started requiring pseudocode before submitting our actual programs. That was sufficiently annoying that I wrote -- in Pascal! -- a pseudocode filter. Then I could resume writing the assignment’s programs directly and then pass them through the filter to fulfill the pseudocode requirement.

[image: CROBOTS]

About this time, I also discovered PROBOTS (Pascal Robots) and CROBOTS (C Robots), which were frameworks for robot battles, with a limited arena and command-set. I spent many hours considering and experimenting with different algorithms!

### College

Once in college, I discovered a computer lab that offered paid part-time work, so I signed up. It was easy work, but more importantly, got me exposure to SunOS as well as to a friendly sysadmin that showed me the ropes (and some after-hours LAN games of [Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descent_(1995_video_game))).  I continued to use Linux on my computer back at the dorm, connecting to OverDrive occasionally, but otherwise playing around with FORTRAN, assembly, and Scheme.  I actually subscribed to the Linux-Kernel mailing list for a few months, until I realized that I couldn’t keep up.  The PC I purchased in college came bundled with an Epson Laserjet 1500 that I kept and used for the next 20+ years!

[image: Epson Laserjet 1500]

A professor threw out an ad-hoc question one Friday: “how many different ways are there to make change for a dollar?”, which resulted in a weekend writing and refining a recursive C program and learning a bit more about US currency -- thousand-dollar bills, anyone? Another part-time job was in the math department, for the Math 100 and 101 courses. I started off grading exams, but that quickly turned into C programming on the VAX there; the program would generate randomized tests -- all with the same structure but with different coefficients or numerical values, to prevent cheating.

Towards the end of college, the time I spent on OverDrive developed into some frequent chats with one particular player that I recognized from days playing in high school. After many late-night chats, mailing photographs back & forth, phone calls, and bus & plane visits, I would eventually marry her :)

### Post-graduation

With all of my UNIX background, it bothered me that every recruiting firm wanted my resume “in Microsoft Word format”, so I wrote my resume in LaTeX and then collected utilities to convert that into over 20 various formats -- none of which were Word. Yes, there was a Makefile!

```
FILES = resume.pdf \
        resume.ps \
        resume.dvi \
        resume_html1 \
        resume_html2 \
        resume.rtf \
        resume.mpx \
        resume.txt \
        resume.b64 \
        resume.uue \
        resume_braille.html \
        resume.1 \
        resume_rot13.txt \
        resume_b1ff.txt \
        resume_chef.txt \
        resume_cockney.txt \
        resume_eleet.txt \
        resume_jive.txt \
        resume_kraut.txt \
        resume_ky00te.txt \
        resume_newspeak.txt \
        resume_nyc.txt
```

I had my eyes on Artificial Intelligence (namely [Logistello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistello)) and cluster computing, so I began collecting 386’s from various surplus auctions, with the hopes of creating my own Beowulf cluster (boot off 3.5” floppy, register with a master node, and receive your slice of the AI puzzle to work on). I then did some math and realized that the power supplies were going to be a strong limiting factor, but that doesn’t mean I didn’t have a bunch of coax-connected computers strung through my apartment at one point!

It’s been a UNIX journey ever since -- including bouts of HP-UX, Irix, SunOS, Debian, Solaris, AIX, and RHEL.

## Why Unix & Linux?

#### But first, Stack Exchange.

My first (official) Stack Exchange experience came when I was trying to solve a particular [Geocaching puzzle](https://www.geocaching.com/geocache/GC217NE_to-market-to-market-through-the-good-grass) with Prolog. I had run into a problem that I couldn’t solve, so I asked: How do I [make a predicate reversible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553022/make-a-predicate-reversible) and was quickly overwhelmed with the quality of the answers; it took me several weeks to digest them and finally accept one.

My first official Unix & Linux activity was on June 1 2015 -- an answer to a [question about NTP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206684/how-to-know-during-system-start-when-system-time-becomes-correct-from-ntp/206738#206738). My first *accepted* answer on U&L came the next day, with [How to turn Diff command into bash script with prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206938/117549).

I’ve certainly learned quite a bit from U&L, from being more careful about using the shell to wrangle text, to being careful with filenames, to the variations in implementations of various utilities. I enjoy answering questions where I can not only solve someone’s particular problem but also maybe teach them a little bit about how the solution worked, so they can integrate that knowledge the next time a similar problem comes up. As in the past, I enjoy making computers do weird things, so I’ve tried [sorting in sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436103/117549) or [sorting in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/482429/117549). I particularly enjoyed seeing someone [adding in sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36959/117549).

As time goes on, I find pleasure in dusting the fixtures and polishing the handles -- namely, coming up with SEDE queries that look for typos or grammatical errors in highly-voted posts or in reviewing recent high-rated posts. I try to get my arms around the tag universe so that we have a sane set of choices for people to assign to their questions and for answerers to follow. I’ve spent quite a bit of time in the review queues, and have earned all six steward badges (1,000+ reviews in each).

Comment: Thank you for the enjoyable answer, Jeff. To paraphrase Tangled, this was an answer worth waiting for. :-)

Answer (score 5):

[image: my network profile]

I studied linguistics and literature at university before I got into IT. My first exposure to Linux was during an exercise that involved installing [Red Hat Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) (presumably version 6.x) on a desktop PC. It was a very long-winded process. I don't think I had ever installed an operating system before that; my experience with PCs was mainly based on DOS 5 (with Windows 3.1 on top) and, later, Windows 98.

The second time came much later, in 2012, when trying out a few things in Ubuntu running in VirtualBox on Windows. Soon after that I became the "accidental (co-)administrator" of a Debian server. A few years later, I also inherited an Ubuntu server. By that time, I had gathered some experience installing Fedora and other packages in order to prepare a few PCs for user tests (i.e. installing the [GPII real-time framework](https://github.com/GPII)). Since these PCs weren't in use most of the time, I also used them to learn how to set up a dual-boot system with Windows 7 and Fedora (we ran user tests on both Windows 7 and Fedora, anyway). After that, I started dual-booting (i.e. Windows 7 and Fedora) on my work laptop. But I still didn't transition to Linux, even though I had wanted to do this for a long time.

When I needed to replace my laptop, Windows 10 had become available, which I did not want to use for [privacy reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10#Privacy_and_data_collection). That is when I started looking for a suitable replacement and I chose Manjaro with Gnome. Why Gnome? I work in [digital accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_accessibility) and Gnome is the Linux desktop environment where accessibility support was most developed. (See [magnification](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Magnification), the  [Orca screen reader](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Orca), the [Gnome on-screen keyboard](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-osk.html), the [ATK accessibility toolkit](https://developer.gnome.org/atk/) and the [Universal access guide](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y.html). Much of that accessibility support existed before Gnome 3 and is also part of Mate.) Manjaro scored very well in a comparative review of five Gnome-based distros in *Linux Format*, so that's what I ended up installing and using as my default OS. I now dual boot with Windows 10 because I can't do some of my accessibility-related work without (occasionally) booting into Windows. Among users with disabilities, Windows is the most frequently used desktop OS. In addition, when teaching about accessible authoring practices, you simply can't ignore Microsoft Office and Adobe Acrobat.

So the main reason for my activity on this site is related to [accessibility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility). (Accessibility also has tags on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accessibility), [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/accessibility), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/accessibility), [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility).)

By the way, this question inspired me to post a [similar one on Language Learning Meta Stack Exchange](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/647/800).

Comment: Thank you for introducing yourself, Christopher. It's been a while since we've had an addition here.

Comment: Thanks for posting. That's really interesting about GNOME/Mate desktops being good choices for users with accessibility requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I purchased my first computer in 2007. At that time I had no formal knowledge of computers. I used it for regular desktop work for almost 4-5 years.

I started using linux with Linux Mint 2 years back.For regular work it was good.I don't know why people say you can't work on linux if you don't know commands. I used Linux Mint almost 7 months without using any command. Then I switched to CentOS, I don't know why. On CentOS I learnt about basic commands.

A2017 was a bad year for 32-bit linux distributions. As CentOS 7 for 32-bit was discontinued, then I moved to Fedora.

I joined unix.stackexchange.com because of trivial issues. If I come across some strange thing, I come here to ask it on the main site or in the chat room.

Most of the users are helpful, they ask you about greater details or simply answer your question. Sometimes they answer in a comment. Well, an answer is an answer if it solves a problem. The questions and chat room interactions are very useful for any rung of learners.!

Comment: Cheers! ........

Comment: using a 32-bit distro nowadays is not good, since you'll lag behind on security updates. Moreover many apps have abandoned the 32-bit version. x86_64 has been there for more than a decade and pretty much any x86 CPUs you can find in the last decade are 64-bit compatible

Comment: I am waiting for the day when Steam goes full x64, will probably take a decade or more as they still seem to have a ton of 32-bit apps on the store and till those aren't 64-bt, Steam won't :(

Answer (score 3):

Today I work as a process supporter (client operation service, 2nd level) for a service company with [a service manager software ITIL framework based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Service_Manager_software).

The job is good regarding the IT environment: Everyday new topics coming from first level problems, a lot of (third level) guys involved but I do not have to be on top of the details. There is the third level that knows the details, and I need to know what problems are hot, have multiple tickets and need to put these problems in a process chain.

I admire people working in a remote, Unix Environment knowing that people there are "technical" intelligent and creative. Am I this person? Or am I the chilled 8 to 5 worker who likes "IT"?
Anyway, the more difficult the problems you can solve, the more job freedom you gain.
As an experienced guy with many IT projects behind me I know it.. anyway let's move back:

When I was a child and a teenager, computers never were important for me. I did not have any patience for playing computer games or programming.
But since I can think I always had a computer at home, as my father was interested in hardware. But me not. I even did not play `Lego` nor watched `Star Wars` and the like.
But I always admired games like `Pirates` and `Populous`.

Time passed and as a young adult, from one day to the other, I was not happy anymore with the client based MS Access database and server-side html homepage  my mother had, updated by me with Macromedia Dreamweaver and MS Access. She represented artists and I wanted to have a php and mysql database solution with one template loading artists on a website, throwing away `Access`.

So I contracted my friend and he did a php site without javascript.
I was envious of his skills and wanted to learn this as well and started with copy and paste JS and PHP code from the Internet...

... a dilemma which took quite long to understand that it is not ok for my learning. Just copying code and understanding nothing is not at all fruitful to make money with IT. Even if you use the top of art tech stack which back then was Jquery!

My first IT job was at a [webshop company](http://www.electronicsales.de) in the "Oberpfalz" in Bavaria, Germany, back in 2012.
I was in my younger thirties and was eager copy and pasting Php/JS code and run Mysql databases.
I was so eager copying that I even realized a CRUD Web App from scratch with Jquery and Php. It should have resulted in a steep learning curve, but in my case: not that much.

During this time, I got a Laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed.

I then changed from Php to Python/Django (using the built-in Django Admin).

In 2015 I wanted to learn more IT and looked into university IT courses, such as FernUni Hagen, Germany. I also got the chance to leverage my `Github` know how especially with `oh-my-zsh`. I took some free time and spent it with my Ubuntu Laptop, Git, [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and [Termux](http://termux.com). I did a lot of research regarding `sed` and `regex` and came by here quite often.

After that I did several projects, most of them giving service as Windows System and Apple Mobile Devices `Admin first and second level`. I could learn `Powershell` and `VBA` which both are great languages.

My visits here are

- learning about [scraping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92461/capturing-screenshot-of-terminal-application-via-shell-script/585149#comment1175976_585149)
- [Display Manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20370/is-there-a-simple-linux-command-that-will-tell-me-what-my-display-manager-is/) Definition
- [Sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105569/bash-replace-space-with-new-line/105581#comment1173683_105581)

Comment: Hi @Timo. Thanks for the answer. It's been a while since this thread was active.